# Facebook graph GET request using python requests module- certificate verification failure

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, python-requests

I am writing a short python script for fun to check a few pages for the amount of likes. I am using the python requests module. As seen below, there was a problem, something about certificates. I am fairly new to programming involving the web, so it's not obvious to me what I should do. `r = requests.get("http://www.google.com/")` correctly returned something.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     r = requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola")
>   routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That error looks like it is coming from OpenSSL. You might have some configuration in your environment that is causing Requests to set the certificate location to something that doesn't contain the certificate you need.

Try investigating the possible ways that Requests might be checking for certificates:

1. It look for configuration using `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable.
2. It checks for curl compatiblity check using `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` environment variable.
3. It tries to import the certifi list if the `certifi` package can be imported.

Check to see if one of `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` or `CURL_CA_BUNDLE` are in your environment:

```
env | egrep "REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE|CURL_CA_BUNDLE"
```

If one of those are set, Requests is probably using that configuration when verifying certificates. If not then Requests is probably using `certifi`. In that case maybe it's worth updating it:

```
pip install -U certifi
```

Failing that, try passing `verify=False` to `requests.get` to have it skip the verification step. I would recommend solving the real problem instead of just switching it off, but that might help you get to the bottom of it.

Comment: The verify=False did the trick. I have certifi, and the egrep turned up nothing. So I am not sure about a real fix, but for my purposes simply no verification worked fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Have you installed [certifi](https://github.com/kennethreitz/certifi)?  A similar issue burned me recently too.  Due to GPL licensing issues, Kenneth Reitz and co have had to move the SSL license bundle to another repo.

I just tried the following with the most up-to-date `certifi` from pypi installed and it seems to work fine:

```
>>> import requests
>>> r = requests.get("https://graph.facebook.com/cocacola") 
>>> r
<Response [200]>
```

More discussion about the licensing woes is available on this [Github Issue thread](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/326) (**Full-discolure**: I was the original poster of that thread).

If a new `certifi` doesn't fix it, you might want to try the [Requests Github Issue page](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues).  They're a very responsive and friendly community!

*Edit*: If an up-to-date `certifi` doesn't fix it, I highly recommend the other poster's suggestion to try `verify=False`

Comment: Thanks for the thought, but with certifi reinstalled it still did not work.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that!  I suspect if you filed an issue on the [Github Issues page](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues), you'd receive a prompt response.