# requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 185090050]

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I get this error when using the requests library. I know it has to do with certificate routine and that I need the cipher RC4-SHA1. How do I go about specifying it when I do
value = requests.get( url )

Comment: answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10667960/2327328