# Python Requests requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, openssl, httprequest, python-requests, ubuntu-12.10

I'm on Ubuntu 12.10 with OpenSSL 1.0.1c, python 2.7.3, [Requests](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/) 1.0.3 and 1.0.4 (tried both), and when attempting to connect to the website in the url variable with the following code.

```
def SendInitialRequest(xmlmessage, redirecturl):
    url = 'https://centineltest.cardinalcommerce.com/maps/txns.asp'

    payload = 'cmpi_msg=' + ET.tostring(xmlmessage)
    headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=None)
    print r.text
```

It throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "clams/libs/centinel/thinclient.py", line 134, in SendInitialRequest
    r = requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=None)
  File "/home/jasonamyers/.virtualenv/clams/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 87, in post
    return request('post', url, data=data, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasonamyers/.virtualenv/clams/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasonamyers/.virtualenv/clams/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 269, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, stream=stream, timeout=timeout, verify=verify, cert=cert, proxies=proxies)
  File "/home/jasonamyers/.virtualenv/clams/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 364, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jasonamyers/.virtualenv/clams/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 163, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Attempting the connection with openssl returns the following:

```
$ openssl s_client -connect centineltest.cardinalcommerce.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
140019346777760:error:140790E5:SSL routines:SSL23_WRITE:ssl handshake failure:s23_lib.c:177:
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 226 bytes
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
---
```

If I force it to use tls1 it works (output truncated):

```
$ openssl s_client -tls1 -connect centineltest.cardinalcommerce.com:443
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=2 C = US, O = "thawte, Inc.", OU = Certification Services Division, OU
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
```

I've seen numerous [bug reports](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openssl/+bug/965371) for this; however, I've not found a way to get around it using the python requests library.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you install openssl through the package manager? If yes, did you check for updates? I can connect to this site using requests.

Comment: I did install openssl via the package manager, there are no updates.  Can you share the versions of everything you are using? Also are you using the built in python or did you use pythonbrews etc to build your own?

Comment: In my case the answer was this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34891294/5953624

Comment: I had this error while trying to connect to an HTTP endpoint using HTTPS. I just changed the url and it worked fine.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Reposting this here for others from [the requests issue page](https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/1083#issuecomment-11853729):

Requests' does not support doing this before version 1. Subsequent to version 1, you are expected to subclass the HTTPAdapter, like so:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

When you've done that, you can do this:

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
```

Any request through that session object will then use TLSv1.

Comment: For the sake of keeping this answer up to date, I did end up writing this up [here](https://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/). The subclass API has changed a little bit since this answer was posted, so you should use the code in that blog post, not the code in this answer. =)

Comment: @Lukasa's link appears to be offline, here is an [archive'ed version](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610021118/http://lukasa.co.uk/2013/01/Choosing_SSL_Version_In_Requests/)

Answer (score 39):

Setting verify=False only skips verifying the server certificate, but will not help to resolve SSL protocol errors.

This issue is likely due to SSLv2 being disabled on the web server, but Python 2.x tries to establish a connection with PROTOCOL_SSLv23 by default. This happens at https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/360aa60b2a36f5f6e9e20325efd8d472f7559b1e/Lib/ssl.py#L1057

You can monkey-patch ssl.wrap_socket() in the ssl module by overriding the ssl_version keyword parameter. The following code can be used as-is. Put this at the start of your program before making any requests.

```
import ssl
from functools import wraps
def sslwrap(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def bar(*args, **kw):
        kw['ssl_version'] = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
        return func(*args, **kw)
    return bar

ssl.wrap_socket = sslwrap(ssl.wrap_socket)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for providing this monkey patch - had been tearing my hair out trying to find a way to set `ssl_version` while using Requests library :)

Comment: Works like a charm!! But what is the scope of this change? Only my program is set to use TLS_1 or is it global?

Comment: As long as the code has been run in any Python invocation, the change will be effective. If you run another Python script/program that doesn't invoke this code, then there is no change. You could put the code into it's own module (.py file) and import this file in any script that needs this override.

Comment: @MA1, please provide more details on the problem you are facing.

Comment: @chnrxn I tried this but still getting issue. The weird thing is i get the issue sometime not always. I have a python3 script that makes lots of connections(not in parallel) to a site. So the workaround i have is retry to connect if SSLError exception comes and this is working.

Comment: I suspect then the root cause of your problem may be with something else. The problem in this thread is about SSL version mismatch between server and client.

Comment: @chnrxn I have applied this patch but now get the error: `urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1409442E:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:tlsv1 alert protocol version` what could this mean?

Comment: @AfromanJ what's the server URL? Looks like a protocol version mismatch between server and client. Can you share your relevant code as well?

Comment: @chnrxn I have an app that scrapes council websites using python and Mechazines. I get this error on a few URLs I try and scrape, one being: http://planning.middevon.gov.uk/online-applications/. Mechazine trys to open the url using urllib `urlopen(url)`. Sorry if thats not enough, any help would be great, thanks.

Comment: @AfromanJ, I got a certificate verification error, which means that the protocol negotiation succeeded. It's probably because our environments are different.

Having said that, this does not seem like the right place to troubleshoot this.

Comment: @chnrx python does not try to use SSLv2 exclusively in this case, it just tries to send an SSLv2-compatible ClientHello message, which may end up using SSLv2, but could use higher version as well.  A server can have SSLv2 support disabled while still allowing SSLv2-compatible ClientHello messages to start the SSL negotation.  But what is happening more and more is that servers are now disabling the acceptance of SSLv2-compatible ClientHello messages as well.

Comment: I don't know why it WORKED and how it WORKED  it just WORKED

Comment: I used this fix and now I get `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:590)`

Answer (score 26):

Installing the "security" package extras for `requests` solved for me:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
sudo pip install -U requests[security]
```

Comment: This fixed a shitty SSL protocol error problem in OSX with stripe SDK, I don't know how I arrived here, but I'm adding some extra google keywords for the future me.
SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590))

Comment: The method fixed my issue, on my Ubuntu(WSL) with Windows 10.

Comment: On a Beaglebone I had to first `sudo apt-get install python3-dev libssl-dev` for the requests[security] install to finish. It still hung for a good couple of minutes, but eventually succeeded. Alas, it made no difference to the `requests` SSL error.

Comment: just "pip install -U requests[security]" fixed my issue.

Answer (score 5):

This is a known bug, you can work it around with a hack:

Open up `site-packages/requests/packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py` (or otherwise just make a local copy of requests inside your own project), and change the block that says:

```
def connect(self):
    # Add certificate verification
    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)

    # Wrap socket using verification with the root certs in
    # trusted_root_certs
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file,
                                cert_reqs=self.cert_reqs,
                                ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
                                server_hostname=self.host,
                                ssl_version=self.ssl_version)
```

to:

```
def connect(self):
    # Add certificate verification
    sock = socket.create_connection((self.host, self.port), self.timeout)

    # Wrap socket using verification with the root certs in
    # trusted_root_certs
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file,
                                cert_reqs=self.cert_reqs,
                                ca_certs=self.ca_certs,
                                server_hostname=self.host,
                                ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

Otherwise, I suppose there's an override somewhere which is less hacky, but I couldn't find one with a few glances.

*NOTE*: On a sidenote, `requests` from PIP (1.0.4) on a MacOS just works with the URL you provided.

Comment: I also had it work perfectly on MacOS, just worried about production, and that when Apple updates OpenSSL that might not always be the case.  Thanks so much for the response.  Gonna see if I'm actually allow to get a custom package like that pushed up to heroku :)

Comment: @jasonamyers: well, you can just make it a part of your project, just copy `requests` folder to your own project and `import requests` will prefer your patched version to the stock one.

Comment: really trying to avoid doing that for one connection out of many others :(  I'll keep digging, thanks for the response.

Comment: I had another deeper look, there's no way `ssl_version` can be overriden from the top of `requests` module, without modifications to the module itself :(

Comment: This isn't an issue on Mac because they use OpenSSL 0.9.8r 8 Feb 2011, which hasn't implemented these changes yet.  My guess is it's just a matter of time :(

Comment: You could also downgrade SSL ;)

Comment: It is worth noting that this same behavior occurs on a mac if you use openssl 1.0.1c :(

Comment: This worked for me, but now I'm getting another error: requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number

Comment: The code you referenced is is `connection.py` not `connectionpool.py`, at least in my version of requests (2.5.3).

Comment: @ChrisJohnson might have changed over time :) it's been 3 years :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue:

> raise SSLError(e)
>   requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

I had fiddler running, I stopped fiddler capture and did not see this error. Could be because of fiddler.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this error, and the fix appears to be turning off SNI, which Python 2.7 does not support:

http://bugs.python.org/issue5639

[urllib3 on python 2.7 SNI error on Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19477214/urllib3-on-python-2-7-sni-error-on-google-app-engine)

Answer (score 3):

To people that can't get above fixes working.

Had to change file ssl.py to fix it.
Look for function create_default_context and change line:

```
context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_SSLv23)
```

to

```
context = SSLContext(PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

Maybe someone can create easier solution without editing ssl.py?

Answer (score 1):

I was having similar issue and I think if we simply ignore the `ssl` verification will work like charm as it worked for me. So connecting to server with `https` scheme but directing them not to verify the certificate.

Using `requests`. Just mention `verify=False` instead of `None`

```
    requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=headers, verify=False)
```

Hoping this will work for those who needs :).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the accepted answer did not work for me. As a temporary workaround you could also use `verify=False` when connecting to the secure website.

From [Python Requests throwing up SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror)

```
requests.get('https://example.com', verify=True)
```

Comment: Its a bad idea to set `verify=False`. You need to figure out what's really broken and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this error when connecting to a RabbitMQ MQTT server via TLS. I'm pretty sure the server is broken but anyway it worked with OpenSSL 1.0.1, but *not* OpenSSL 1.0.2.

You can check your version in Python using this:

```
import ssl
ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
```

I'm not sure how to downgrade OpenSSL within Python (it seems to be statically linked on Windows at least), other than using an older version of Python.