# The equivalent of curl code in requests

Tags: curl, python-requests

I have the following curl, which I need it to work from python using the requests package.

```
curl -s -H 'Accept: application/xml' 'https://xyz.com'
```

I tried the following with no success. Can you see what am I doing wrong here?

```
headers = {'Accept': 'application/xml'} 
print requests.get("https://xyz.com", headers=headers)
```

After some seconds I get this:

```
print requests.get("https://xyz.com", headers=headers)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
return request('get', url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 383, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 486, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 389, in send
raise SSLError(e)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

Fix: The calls weren't equivalent because the curl call was http, whereas the requests call was https.

Comment: "no success" doesn't really say much - please elaborate on what didn't work!

Comment: Fair enough. I edited the question. Thanks!

Comment: maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748994/python-ssl-connection-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol ?

Comment: Just noticed that the url wasn't https, but just http. Any other idea?

Comment: but then the error message doesn't fit

Comment: That's where the mess up was. The curl call was http, whereas the requests was https. I should delete this question. Thanks a lot.

Comment: sometimes just talking about a problem can make oneself realize the problem. Glad to be of service as [rubber duck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) ;)

Comment: I'm getting myself a rubber duck :)

Comment: have you looked at this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17916285/ssl-version-in-httplib2-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `verify` argument for SSL verification like this:

```
requests.get("https://xyz.com", headers=headers, verify=True)
```

Hope this will help ;)