# Getting SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python-2.7, ssl-certificate, tornado

I am using tornado framework and doing certificate authentication but I am getting following error :

SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:510: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

I am using below code:

```
http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(HomeHandler()
              ,ssl_options=dict(
               certfile="cert/certificate.crt",
               keyfile="cert/certificate.key",
               cert_reqs=ssl.CERT_REQUIRED,
               ca_certs="cert/cacertificate.crt",
               #ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
               )
               )
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: which version of python 2.7? there was some problems in older ones with ssl version as in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748994/python-ssl-connection-eof-occurred-in-violation-of-protocol

Comment: What exactly are you doing that triggers this error? Does it happen all the time or does it just appear in your logs? If the latter, it may be the normal result of a client going away (this is logged less noisily in the most recent versions of tornado)

Comment: @kAlmAcetA: I am using Python 2.7.8 and tornado '4.0' version

Comment: @BenDarnell: yes it appear in my logs all the time. I have tried couple of monkey patches but could not resolve it.

Comment: This error should no longer be logged in Tornado 4.2.

Comment: @BenDarnell: Do we have any patch for tornado 4.0 to make this working ?

Comment: The log messages are harmless, everything is working. You could dig through the git logs if you want to backport the logging change, but I would really recommend upgrading to 4.3 instead.

Comment: @BenDarnell: Thank you

Comment: @BenDarnell since this is solution (ignore or upgrade), consider posting an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have upgraded tornado version to 4.3 and no ssl error I am getting now.