# urllib3 on python 2.7 SNI error on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, sni, urllib3

I'm trying to download an HTTPS page from my site hosted on Google App Engine with SNI.
No matter what library I use, I get the following error:

```
[Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

I've tried solving the error in many ways, including using the urllib3 openssl monkeypatch:

```
from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3
```

But I always get the same error mentioned above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure if this is a typo in your question, but the line should be `pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()` — that is, it's a function call, not a property access.

Comment: You are completely right! my stupid mistake.. tested and worked, thanks :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately for urllib3, the Python standard library did not add SNI support until Python 3.2.
(See [Issue #118 @ urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/118))

To use SNI in Python 2.7 with urllib3, you'll need to use the PyOpenSSL injection monkeypatch.
(See [Issue #156 @ urllib3](https://github.com/shazow/urllib3/pull/156))

```
from urllib3.contrib import pyopenssl
pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()
```

Your question basically had the same code, except it was missing the parentheses call on the `pyopenssl.inject_into_urllib3()` call. Fixing that should do the trick.

You'll also need to make sure to have the following dependencies available:

- pyOpenSSL (tested with 0.13)
- ndg-httpsclient (tested with 0.3.2)
- pyasn1 (tested with 0.1.6)