# SSLv3 alert handshake failure with urllib2

Tags: python, python-2.7, ssl, openssl, urllib2

I'm having troubles connecting with https using urllib2 under Python 2.7.10.

Any thoughts what I'm missing?

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun 18 2015, 10:53:24) 
[GCC 4.4.5] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl, urllib2
>>> ssl.HAS_SNI
True
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 0.9.8o 01 Jun 2010'
>>> opener = urllib2.build_opener()
>>> opener.open('https://twitrss.me/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 431, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 449, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 409, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1240, in https_open
    context=self._context)
  File "/usr/local/python2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1197, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)>
```

Comment: This problem does not happen to me on Windows with Python 2.7.10.  But it does happen to me on OS X with Python 2.7.11.  I am trying to open PayPal.

Comment: I have confirmed this problem happens on OS X with Python 2.7.10.  So Windows with Python 2.7.10 works fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to duplicate your problem on OS X 10.10.3, whose stock Python is 2.7.6 built with OpenSSL 0.9.8zd.

The problem is the lack of the [Server Name Indication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (SNI) extension in the TLS handshake, which the twitrss.me site apparently requires:

> Server Name Indication (SNI) is an extension to the TLS computer
>   networking protocol by which a client indicates which hostname it
>   is attempting to connect to at the start of the handshaking process.

I verified this by writing a small C++ program with OpenSSL, and inserting the OpenSSL call

```
SSL_set_tlsext_host_name(ssl, "twitrss.me");
```

allows a successful connection while omitting it fails. I also looked at packet dumps to verify that SNI was missing when attempting connection using Python.

The Python SSL module apparently [supports SNI in Python 3](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/community/faq/#what-are-hostname-doesn-t-match-errors) but [may require a workaround in Python 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19477363/1462337). It appears that [PEP 0466](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0466/) includes SNI and landed in Python 2.7.9, so you should have it, but I don't know if `urllib2/urllib3` take advantage of that without the workaround.

Comment: *"I verified this by writing a small C++ program..."* - `openssl s_client -connect twitrss.me:443 -tls1 -servername twitrss.me` works fine, too. No programming required. `-servername` is the SNI option.