# Python: get website source code using urllib2 (ssl problems)

Tags: python, ssl, urllib2

As I mentioned in the title, I want to read the source code of a website. Everything is working fine, but sometimes I get an Error.

**Error**

```
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

I know that there is a problem with the ssl certificate, but I don't know how to fix it. I already spent several hours to find a solution to my problem, but until now I was not successful (I have already tried a couple things with the `ssl` module).

**The way I do it:**

```
import urllib2
urllib2.openurl("https://www.website.com")
```

If there is no way doing this kind of stuff with `urllib2`, is there a different module, which you recommend?

Comment: PS: I am using python2.7.10

Comment: Handshake failure might be anything like missing SNI or an old OpenSSL version which does not support newer protocols or ciphers. You might try requests library which depending on the unknown cause of the problem might work better or fail too. If this does not help provide information about platform, OpenSSL version (`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`)  and target URL so that others can  reproduce the problem and help you.

Comment: 'OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016'

Comment: Since the target URL is still unknown my guess is that it requires either ciphers like ECDHE and/or protocol versions like TLS 1.2 which are not available in this obsolete OpenSSL version. You might check with [ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html). In this case upgrade everything to use a newer OpenSSL.

Comment: Website: bs.to!

Comment: Can you do something with the URL?

Comment: Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: My guess this is related to SNI which is required by this target. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918761/sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-with-urllib2.

Answer (score 0):

It might be happening due to some ssl options that the server requests and `urllib2` library doesn't support.

I recommend you to install and use `request` library as it provides more security packages and options.

Comment: what kind of error do you get when you use `request` ?

Comment: This: requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)

Comment: Can you do something with this?

Comment: Does it happen when you're trying to connect to ANY host or just the one that you specified in the question?

Comment: Just to a specific host!

Comment: Have you found a solution for my problem?