# Unable to fetch url in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urllib2

I was not able to fetch url from biblegateway.com here it shows error as
`urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure>` Please don't make duplicate as i went throught the sites which shown in duplicate i didn't understand by visiting that site .

here is my code

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+1&version=NIV'
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)
html = response.read()
print html
```

Comment: Which python? Compare to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30918761/sslv3-alert-handshake-failure-with-urllib2 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649390/python-requests-ssl-handshake-failure

Comment: I am using python 2.7 @dave_thompson_085

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python requests ssl handshake failure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31649390/python-requests-ssl-handshake-failure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a good reference for [fetching url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15138614/how-can-i-read-the-contents-of-an-url-with-python).

In python 3 you can have:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
URL = 'https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Deuteronomy+1&version=NIV'
f = urlopen(URL)
myfile = f.read()
print(myfile)
```

Not sure it clears a ssl problem though. Maybe some clues [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error).

Comment: its showing `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'request'` @Evgeny

Comment: Are running it in python 3?

Comment: Its working now by replaing `import urllib` by  `import urllib.request` @ Evgeny

Comment: right, in 3.6 it does. does it bypass ssl error though?

Comment: also, [requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/) is a lot easier, more high level than `urllib`