# How to disable SSLv3 in java 1.8

Tags: java, rest-assured, sslhandshakeexception

I am trying to test a rest api by using **Rest Assured** in **java 1.8**.
i am getting the below error when sending a request.
The API URI doesnt allow SSLv3 and SSLv2. 
I have already tested by setting the system property to TLSv1.2.
I have imported the certificate to cacerts. Nothing helped here.

Can someone tell me if something else could be causing an issue.

Below is the error.

```
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:553)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:412)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:179)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.ManagedClientConnectionImpl.open(ManagedClientConnectionImpl.java:328)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:612)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:447)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:884)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:82)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55)
at org.apache.http.client.HttpClient$execute$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl$RestAssuredHttpBuilder.doRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2028)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.doRequest(HTTPBuilder.java:494)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder.request(HTTPBuilder.java:451)
at io.restassured.internal.http.HTTPBuilder$request$2.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:138)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendHttpRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1434)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.sendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1221)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:146)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.SendRequestFilter.filter(SendRequestFilter.groovy:30)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter$0.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.time.TimingFilter.filter(TimingFilter.java:56)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.log.RequestLoggingFilter.filter(RequestLoggingFilter.java:124)
at io.restassured.filter.Filter$filter.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:138)
at io.restassured.internal.filter.FilterContextImpl.next(FilterContextImpl.groovy:72)
at io.restassured.filter.FilterContext$next.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:110)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:130)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1631)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:179)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1637)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:179)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:166)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:807)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:151)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:163)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:194)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.get(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at com.isango.api.automation.tests.testRestAssuredApi.getTicketFilterList(testRestAssuredApi.java:263)
at com.isango.api.automation.tests.testRestAssuredApi.testTicketFilterList(testRestAssuredApi.java:137)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:661)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:869)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1193)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:126)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:744)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:602)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
... 151 more
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL peer shut down incorrectly in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908835/ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-in-java)

Comment: That answer did not work for me.

        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

Comment: Unless I am much mistaken, Java ceased supporting SSLv3 several versions before 1.8. There is no evidence here that the TLS version was the problem. `https.protocols` only works with `HttpsURLConnection`, not with the Apache HTTP client. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Well i am also not sure of the exact issue that could be causing this error as it is too generic..i just checked the API url and it does not allow SSLv3 so i guessed may be this could be the issue.
i just checked [link]https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https

Comment: `  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake`  means the server closed the connection. Indeed it could be caused by not providing mutual SSL when required or using unsupported version of TLS or ciphers. you could use `-Djavax.net.debug=ssl:handshake` to see what is really used

Answer (score 1):

This errors means that, your host cannot establish a secure connection with the server according to the following reasons :

1. May be your certification at the host not the same as the server,
2. OR the host certification didn't store in the right trust store
3. OR your JDK load certification from its security folder which is not contain the server certifications.
4. OR The server IP didn't store in the Host (hosts file)
5. OR the server didn't allow access to its certification, so you should allow your host to access the server certification.

you can follow the official link for Oracle to know how to disable SSL 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html

Comment: I have checked all the points that you have mentioned. Added the server certificate to the trust store of the jdk security folder.
server IP added to the host file.
the server doesnt block any access.
Still didnt work.

Comment: Try to check the server certification .. you can add host's ip in your server certification that enable only those ips configured ... So try to add your host ip to the server certification in order to pass handshaking step ..