# how to use multi part file attachment using Rest-assured in Java?

Tags: java, rest, rest-assured

I am trying to execute post request using rest-assured with multipart/form-data, the request contains with a url with parameters and file to be attached

Below is the code which I am trying and getting handshake error
how can I attach a file with url ?

```
RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured
                                    .given()
                                    .relaxedHTTPSValidation()
                                    .cookie("SESSION", cookieVal)
                                    .header("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data")
                                    .header("accept","application/json")
                                    .multiPart(new File("CorporateWallpaper.jpg")) ;

Response response = httpRequest.request().post(url);
System.out.print(response.getStatusCode());
```

Actual result

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1321)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1160)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:533)
```

Comment: Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh) ?

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure about your environment.
Found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908835/ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-in-java), can you check protocol versions once.