# service.users().messages().get() error : java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: gmail-api

```
// build.gradle

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

mainClassName = 'GmailQuickstart'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
version = '1.0'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.28.0')
    compile('com.google.oauth-client:google-oauth-client-jetty:1.28.0')
    compile('com.google.apis:google-api-services-gmail:v1-rev101-1.25.0')
}

// GmailQuickstart.java

// Copyright 2018 Google LLC
//
// Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
// you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
// You may obtain a copy of the License at
//
//     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
//
// Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
// distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
// WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
// See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
// limitations under the License.

// [START gmail_quickstart]

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.GmailScopes;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class GmailQuickstart {
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Gmail API Java Quickstart";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    private static final String TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH = "tokens";

    /**
     * Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved tokens/ folder.
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES = new ArrayList<String>();
    static {
        SCOPES.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_LABELS);
        SCOPES.add(GmailScopes.GMAIL_READONLY);
    }
    private static final String CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH = "/credentials.json";

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @param HTTP_TRANSPORT The network HTTP Transport.
     * @return An authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException If the credentials.json file cannot be found.
     */
    private static Credential getCredentials(final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT) throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = GmailQuickstart.class.getResourceAsStream(CREDENTIALS_FILE_PATH);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(new FileDataStoreFactory(new java.io.File(TOKENS_DIRECTORY_PATH)))
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        LocalServerReceiver receiver = new LocalServerReceiver.Builder().setPort(8888).build();
        return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, receiver).authorize("user");
    }

    public static void main(String... args) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

        // Build a new authorized API client service.
        final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

        // Print the labels in the user's account.
        String userId = "me";
        List<String> labelIds = new ArrayList<String>();
        labelIds.add("INBOX");
        String query = "from:XXXXX";

        ListMessagesResponse response = service.users().messages().list(userId)
            .setLabelIds(labelIds).setQ(query).execute();

        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<>();
        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = service.users().messages().list(userId).setLabelIds(labelIds).setQ(query)
                    .setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        for (Message message : messages) {
            //System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
            System.out.println("Message id: " + message.getId());
            message = service.users().messages().get(userId, message.getId()).execute();
            System.out.println(message.getSnippet());
        }
    }
}
// [END gmail_quickstart]
```

This is the full sample starting from https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java
I adjusted some parts to get mail message contents from my gmail account.

I could get the message id but when I tried to get the content of it, it showed the error below.

```
Message id: 16977563d41f0b93
Exception in thread "main" javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1413)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:162)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:142)
        at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:84)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1040)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:515)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:448)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:565)
        at GmailQuickstart.main(GmailQuickstart.java:110)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:983)
        ... 13 more
```

I added

> System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");

too

UPDATE:

Now with the exactly same code with only TLSv.1.2, it runs. I think it would be the server-side issue which provides mail contents through gmail API. But sometimes it shows the error above.

[image]

Comment: Instead of adding only `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1.2");`, try to add more versions of protocols in system property like `System.setProperty("https.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");`, this implementation was discussed in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28908835/ssl-peer-shut-down-incorrectly-in-java).

Comment: Actually I did it but the result was the same. Now with the exactly same code with only TLSv.1.2, it runs. I think it would be the server-side issue which provides mail contents through gmail API.
But sometimes it shows the error above.