# SonarQube Analysis fails although retrieval of issues from remote server succeeds

Tags: java, eclipse, sonarqube

I have SonarQube installed as a plugin in Eclipse, on a machine connected behind a corporate firewall. I am able to access the website of the sonar server (available on a remote machine outside the local network) using the internal browser in Eclipse. The analysis runs successfully with my current configuration when I am not behind the firewall. When I am behind the firewall, the project association, connection test of the server configuration and retrieval of remote issues of projects works fine. The analysis fails with the following error message:

```
Retrieve remote issues of project ***...
Start SonarQube analysis on ***...
Exception in thread "main" org.sonar.runner.kevinsawicki.HttpRequest$HttpRequestException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
...
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

I have tried providing the proxy authentication details as "JVM arugments for preview analysis" in the SonarQube preference, but this causes even the server connection test to fail. The connection test only passes with "Native" configuration and fails with both "Manual" and "Direct" on Eclipse, even with proxy settings configured.

Is there a way to configure the analysis to run successfully using a server from across the firewall?

Comment: This is not a problem with SonarQube here but a networking problem; is your proxy correctly configured with Java?

Comment: The proxy configurations are also used with SVN and that seems to work fine...

Answer (score 0):

You're likely facing a certificate issue rather than a network issue related to a proxy. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21589728/4940316) regarding configuring certificates in the JDK running Eclipse

Comment: Does not work... Copied certificates (extracted from the web browser) to security folder and tried after restarting system and eclipse, still shows same error.