# Java socket:- javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during

Tags: java, sockets, tomcat, ssl

I see this error reported by lots of people but none of the solution worked for me. I am trying to establish listen port of 443 on an application deployed in tomat a separate port for better performance. I am not able to bind the SSL certificate to this port. I keep on getting below error. As mentioned in [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh), I have added below JVM parameter but still did not resolve the problem. The one issue I see is, the CSR request was generated using openssl and converted in jks format for keytool to read.

`-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2`

I am using java version "1.8.0_151" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_151-b12). Also I tried checking the details in https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.htm and everything seems to be proper on this port, but still I am getting this error.

**Error trace from log file**

```
socket[8dd49b[SSL_NULL_WITH_NULL_NULL: Socket[addr=/10.190.23.10,port=23456,localport=443]]] will be closed.
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1002)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1385)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:938)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
        at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:71)
```

**SSL debug trace**

```
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Thread-7845, received EOFException: error
Thread-7845, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Thread-7845, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Thread-7845, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 28                               ......(
Thread-7845, called closeSocket()
Thread-7845, called close()
Thread-7845, called closeInternal(true)
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
Thread-7851, received EOFException: error
Thread-7851, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
Thread-7851, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
Thread-7851, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
```

Comment: you have installed the ssl certificates?

Comment: Yes I have installed certificates signed from a valid CA

Comment: Can you set for the test only your self signed cerificate?