# Camel FTPs how enable TLS resumption

Tags: ssl, apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I have a camel FTPS Route which connetcs to an FTPS Server with enabled "**Require TLS session resumption on data connection when seing PROT P**"

Is there a possiblity on http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html to enable this option. I didn't found anything similar. The Filezilla Server runs on a customers server and cannot be modified.

My Route is configured now like this

```
ftps://cent@CUSTOMERS_IP:990//?antInclude=**%2F*.tif&autoCreate=false&binary=true&disconnect=true&ftpClient.keyStore.file=D%3A%2FCent%2Fjboss-fuse%2Fetc%2Fcent-fuse.jks&ftpClient.keyStore.keyPassword=xxxxxx&ftpClient.keyStore.password=xxxxxx&isImplicit=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=100&move=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.done&moveFailed=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.error&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx&readLock=markerFile&recursive=false&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&securityProtocol=SSL&sortBy=file%3Aname&stepwise=false] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[ftps://cent@46.14.136.146:990//?antInclude=**%2F*.tif&autoCreate=false&binary=true&disconnect=true&ftpClient.keyStore.file=D%3A%2FCent%2Fjboss-fuse%2Fetc%2Fcent-fuse.jks&ftpClient.keyStore.keyPassword=xxxxxx&ftpClient.keyStore.password=xxxxxx&isImplicit=true&maxMessagesPerPoll=100&move=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.done&moveFailed=%24%7Bfile%3Aname%7D.error&passiveMode=true&password=xxxxxx&readLock=markerFile&recursive=false&scheduler=quartz2&scheduler.cron=0+0%2F5+*+*+*+%3F&securityProtocol=SSL&sortBy=file%3Aname&stepwise=false
```

And I have follow Error now

```
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.listFiles(FtpOperations.java:821)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.doPollDirectory(FtpConsumer.java:122)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpConsumer.pollDirectory(FtpConsumer.java:82)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:131)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)[232:org.apache.camel.camel-core:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.apache.camel.pollconsumer.quartz2.QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.execute(QuartzScheduledPollConsumerJob.java:61)[348:org.apache.camel.camel-quartz2:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)[346:org.quartz-scheduler.quartz:2.2.2]
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)[346:org.quartz-scheduler.quartz:2.2.2]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host closed connection during handshake
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:992)[:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)[:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)[:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)[:1.8.0_131]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPSClient._openDataConnection_(FTPSClient.java:619)[216:org.apache.commons.net:3.3.0.redhat-3]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:759)[216:org.apache.commons.net:3.3.0.redhat-3]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3293)[216:org.apache.commons.net:3.3.0.redhat-3]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3271)[216:org.apache.commons.net:3.3.0.redhat-3]
    at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2930)[216:org.apache.commons.net:3.3.0.redhat-3]
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.FtpOperations.listFiles(FtpOperations.java:814)[251:org.apache.camel.camel-ftp:2.17.0.redhat-630224]
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:505)[:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)[:1.8.0_131]
    ... 17 more
09:05:01,947 | WARN  | etadata_Worker-2 | SftpOperations                   | 251 - org.apache.camel.camel-ftp - 2.17.0.redhat-630224 | JSCH -> Permanently added 'egkpercosrelay-int.apps.cent-systems.swiss' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
09:05:01,947 | WARN  | etadata_Worker-2 | SftpOperations      

         | 2
```

Comment: Possibly related to [JDK problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21245796/javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-remote-host-closed-connection-during-handsh)