# Having SSL error while trying to connect to Twitter Streaming API

Tags: python, ssl, twitter, openssl, tweepy

I'm having some SSL error when trying to connect to the Twitter Streaming API using Tweepy package. I read about about SSL certificates not being valid, but I couldn't solve the problem. What is weird is that sometimes it works fine, and sometimes it doesn't, without even touching to the code.
Here is my error log:

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 299, in filter
    self._start(async)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 236, in _start
    self._run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tweepy/streaming.py", line 157, in _run
    conn.connect()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1176, in connect
    self.sock = ssl.wrap_socket(sock, self.key_file, self.cert_file)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 387, in wrap_socket
    ciphers=ciphers)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 143, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 305, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
SSLError: [Errno 8] _ssl.c:507: EOF occurred in violation of protocol
```

I'm using the typical way to connect :

```
# Authentification
auth = OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token (access_token, access_token_secret)

# Connecting to the stream
twitterStream = Stream (auth, twitterListener())
twitterStream.filter(track=['someWord'])
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Maybe this one helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102416/python-requests-requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-8-ssl-c504-eof-occurred

Comment: Yup, ssl.wrap_socket() is being called. My answer would help. :)