# Why do I keep getting IOError: [Errno socket error] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581) error?

Tags: python, sockets, urllib

I'm using urllib to send multiple requests to an API. Sometimes in the middle of the requests I get this error `IOError: [Errno socket error] EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:581)` . Though I've handled the exception but I still don't know the explanation of why it occurs. I've seen some `_ssl.c:504` error threads. Is there any similarity in both errors ? Is this a known bug in urllib ?

Comment: You can try the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24166498/41957, but without a more detailed stack trace, it is hard to pinpoint your specific problem. Please provide a stack trace if you can.

Comment: For those looking for an answer to this problem when using `youtube-dl`: update to the latest version. Version 2015.06.04 solved that problem for me.