# **[Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol. only on windows 8.1

Tags: python-2.7, ssl, windows-8.1, python-requests

i have been running an application on Python 2.7 on Windows XP using requests for a REST interface, all worked ok for 2 years.

Now i am using the same application on windows 8.1 (same Python and requests), the application is very slow and i get this error sometimes: 
**[Errno 8] _ssl.c:504: EOF occurred in violation of protocol.**

I have verify set to False.
I have read on this site multiple posts about possible solutions, but they don't work for me, also i am getting the error sometimes and **only on windows 8.1**, not every time i do a GET or POST. Could this be related to Windows 8.1?

Comment: Can you try if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24166498/41957 ?

Comment: Yes, thank you, i found it before and used it few weeks ago.

Comment: Thank you. Hope you have upvoted the answer as well. :)

Comment: I try to upvote but it tells me a need to have 15 of reputation.