# Having SSL problems with requests.get in Python

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, beautifulsoup, python-requests

First I will say that I am not very knowledgeable in any language. I took a few classes in college and never really followed up. So bear with me.

I am using python 2.7 on windows 7.

So I'm trying to write something basic to scrape, parse, and analyze data from a particular website. I got as far as realizing I should get be using requests, BeautifulSoup, and lxml.

It is a secured website. The website uses TLS 1.0. The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC with SHA 1 for message authentication, and RSA as the key exchange mechanism. None of this really means anything to me. Any of this prohibitive?

The code thats giving me problems:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import requests

results = request.get(url)
```

The trace this gives is as follows:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/User/PycharmProjects/untitled/jkh.py", line 6, in <module>
    results = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 69, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 50, in request
    response = session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 465, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 573, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 431, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)
```

I tried adding a verify=false parameter which didn't work. That resulted in the same trace.

When I try to connect to the site using openSSL and forcing tls1 as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102416/python-requests-requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-8-ssl-c504-eof-occurred) I get:

```
Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

This hangs up for a few minutes before giving me:

```
read:errno 10054
error in s_client
```

This code works but I'm not totally clear on what Sessions is and how I'd move forward from here. Credit to stackflow user jasonamyers

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
import ssl

class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

import requests
s = requests.Session()
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
```

Help?

EDIT: Looks like I had everything I needed. This code works:

```
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
    from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
    import ssl

    class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
        def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
            self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                           maxsize=maxsize,
                                           block=block,
                                           ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)

    import requests
    s = requests.Session()
    s.mount('url', MyAdapter())

    results = s.get(url)
```

Comment: RTFM on how to proceed http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/?highlight=session#request-sessions