# Requests requests.exceptions.SSLError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests

I'm trying to download files from a website that uses HttpBasicAuth. Everything worked fine on an Ubuntu machine but not when I tried to run my script on a Windows machine. I have problems downloading files from that website using requests. Below is the code relevant to my problem:

Initial code that works on Ubuntu:

```
url = 'https://abc.example.com'
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
s.auth = (creds['user'], creds['passwd'])
filename = "somefile.txt"
download_url = url + "/" + filename
resp = s.get(download_url)  # fails on this line when run in Windows
```

I did a `verify=False` because I'm having `SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed.` if I don't. I don't understand fully what that means and I would appreciate an explanation. From how I understood it, requests just cannot verify the server's cert. Similarly, it seemed that my browser does not recognize the certificate either as seen below.

[image: browser cannot recognize]

Anyways, so I ran the script on Windows that has pretty much the same python version (2.7.x) and I got this:

[image: exception shown]

I did a quick search and found some fixes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14102416/python-requests-requests-exceptions-sslerror-errno-8-ssl-c504-eof-occurred) and found a [github issue here](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie/issues/315). I followed the first fix and changed my code to:

```
url = 'https://abc.example.com'
s = requests.Session()
s.verify = False
s.auth = (creds['user'], creds['passwd'])
s.mount('https://', MyAdapter())
# .. omitted code similar to the one above ..
resp = s.get(download_url)
```

I added the class specified in the answer

```
class MyAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,
                                       maxsize=maxsize,
                                       block=block,
                                       ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
```

It is still showing the same errors.

From the github issue, they were checking the OpenSSL version, so I did a check on the Windows machine and if I remember correctly it is `1.0.2a`. I did a check on the Ubuntu machine where the initial version was working, it is `1.0.1f`.

EDIT:

Python version in Ubuntu: 2.7.6 (works here)

Python version in Windows: 2.7.10 (does not work here)

Comment: Have you checked that your root certificates are up to date on your Windows machine?

Comment: Do not add text as images, copy/paste it instead.

Comment: Sniffing the traffic may tell what exactly is wrong. If there's a protocol violation, the error probably corresponds to packet structure which is not encrypted.

Comment: Since the stack trace shows "adapter.py", the problem can be in the Adapter i.e. in the code differences rather that OS differences.

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I found it weird as well because doesn't python have the same code for the modules across different OSes? If that i so, then the initial code without using MyAdapter should have worked.

Comment: In YOUR code differences. The Linux code doesn't use any `Adapter`s. From what I can see, you run _different_ code on Linux and Wnidows. If it's not so, please edit your question to clearly restate your steps: what you've run, where, and with what results. It's unclear now, and we're no psychics.

Comment: I don't see why it's unclear. I ran the first snippet for both machines but since it did not work in Windows, I have to make changes which still produced the same error.

Comment: "... pretty much the same python version (2.7.x) " - please make sure that you are using at least version 2.7.9, which is the first 2.7.x version supporting [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication). Having SNI  support on one platform but not on the other might explain the different behavior.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I updated my question to show the exact versions. It is odd that it works on the earlier version of python

Comment: @krato: can you publish the URL of this site so one is able to reproduce the problem? My guess is that it is somehow related to the setup of this site.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich, sorry but the URL is from the company I'm developing for and is confidential. I also guess that the site's setup can be causing problems knowing that chrome itself cannot verify the certificate but I still think there may be some way to go around this since it worked on an Ubuntu system with a different python version.

Comment: @krato: I'm sure that it can be worked around. But since the exact cause of the problem is not known so far it is not possible to say **how** it can be worked around.