# Web Scraping from drop down values on a web page

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to scrape the data from a webpage having drop down values. The Url_list & all_urls both are producing exactly the same URLs i want, but the code is failing due to connection error each time.

Below is the code i have used

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re
import pandas as pd
import json

all_urls=[]
Data =[]
url_list=[]
url = 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/'
page = 'https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/info'
text = requests.get(url).text
d = re.findall(r'var\s*cObject\s*=\s*(.*)\s*;', text)[0]
d = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', d)
d = json.loads(d.replace("'", '"'))
for c in d['category']:
    AC = [c['permalinks']]
    urls = url + AC[0]
    all_urls.append(urls)


for info in all_urls:
    pages = requests.get(info)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')
    script_sections = soup.find_all('script')
    for i in range(len(script_sections)):
        if len(script_sections[i].contents) >= 1:
            txt = script_sections[i].contents[0]
            pattern = re.compile(r'permalink:\'(.*?)\'')
            permlinks = re.findall(pattern, txt)
            for i in permlinks:
                href = "../info/{{permalink}}"
                href = href.split('{')[0]+i
                full_url = urljoin(page, href)
                url_list.append(full_url)
            for m in url_list:
                entry=[]
                Newpages = requests.get(m)
                soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(Newpages.content, 'html.parser')
                Member = soup_2.find_all('h5', attrs={'class' :'w3-text-sfma'})
                Member_Name = [Member_Name.text.strip() for Member_Name in Member]
                Details = soup_2.find_all('p')
                other_details = [other_details.text.strip() for other_details in Details]
                Details_final = other_details[1:9]
                Address = Details_final[0:4]
                Tel = [y for y in Details_final if y.startswith('Tel')]
                Fax = [m for m in Details_final if m.startswith('Fax')]
                Email = [n for n in Details_final if n.startswith('Email')]
                Website =  [s for s in Details_final if s.startswith('Website')]
                entry.append(Member_Name)
                entry.append(Address)
                entry.append(Tel)
                entry.append(Fax)
                entry.append(Email)
                entry.append(Website)
                Data.append(entry)
```

The error i am getting is

```
SysCallError: (10054, 'WSAECONNRESET')
```

Comment: Probable duplicate : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38761166/ssl-bad-handshake-error-10054-wsaeconnreset

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for all the suggestions & answers !!
i could finally got almost everything in place. Below is the code ihave used

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.parse import urljoin
import re
import pandas as pd
import json
import requests


Data =[]
url_list=[]
urls_list =[]
url = "https://www.sfma.org.sg/member/category/"
text = requests.get(url).text
d = re.findall(r'var\s*cObject\s*=\s*(.*)\s*;', text)[0]
d = re.sub(r'(\w+)(?=:)', r'"\1"', d)
d = json.loads(d.replace("'", '"'))
for c in d['category']:
    AC = [c['permalink']]
    urls = url + AC[0]
    url_list.append(urls)
for m in url_list:
        pages = requests.get(m)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')
        script_sections = soup.find_all('script')
        for i in range(len(script_sections)):
               if len(script_sections[i].contents) >= 1:
                    txt = script_sections[i].contents[0]
                    pattern = re.compile(r'permalink:\'(.*?)\'')
                    permlinks = re.findall(pattern, txt)

                    for i in permlinks:
                        AE = [i['permalink'] for i in d['category'] if 'permalink' in i]
                        if i not in AE:
                            href = "../info/{{permalink}}"
                            href = href.split('{')[0]+i
                            full_url = urljoin(url, href)
                            urls_list.append(full_url)  
        for n in urls_list:
                        entry=[]
                        pages = requests.get(n)
                        soup_2 =BeautifulSoup(pages.content, 'html.parser')
                        Member = soup_2.find_all('h5', attrs={'class' :'w3-text-sfma'})
                        Member_Name = [Member_Name.text.strip() for Member_Name in Member]
                        Details = soup_2.find_all('p')
                        other_details = [other_details.text.strip() for other_details in Details]
                        Details_final = other_details[1:9]
                        Address = Details_final[0:4]
                        Tel = [y for y in Details_final if y.startswith('Tel')]
                        Fax = [m for m in Details_final if m.startswith('Fax')]
                        Email = [n for n in Details_final if n.startswith('Email')]
                        Website =  [s for s in Details_final if s.startswith('Website')]
                        entry.append(Member_Name)
                        entry.append(Address)
                        entry.append(Tel)
                        entry.append(Fax)
                        entry.append(Email)
                        entry.append(Website)
                        entry.append(Category_Name)
                        Data.append(entry)
```

Thanks to All!!!