# Error when posting Pandas DF to Google Sheets using API -- bypassed by converting to csv then back to DF

Tags: python, pandas, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am posting the results of a webscrape to Google Sheets using the API. The results are stored using a Pandas DataFrame in Python. Keep in mind that I am posting to multiple sheets within one spreadsheet, each identified by **sheetName**. Here is the code I am using to post the DF:

```
def df_to_sheet(sheet, sheetName, df):
   try:
       df.replace(np.nan, '', inplace=True)
       df = df.T.reset_index().T.values.tolist()
       inputRange = sheetName + '!A1'

       response = sheet.values().update(
           spreadsheetId=sheets_conn.SPREADSHEET_ID,
           valueInputOption='RAW',
           range=inputRange,
           body=dict(
               majorDimension='ROWS',
               values=df
               )
       ).execute()
       print(response)
       return True
   except:
       return False
```

On all but two sheets are posting just fine. However, on those two sheets (with the try/except removed) return this error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1725, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1441, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1364, in _conn_request
    conn.request(method, request_uri, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1282, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1328, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1277, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1076, in _send_output
    self.send(chunk)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 998, in send
    self.sock.sendall(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1236, in sendall
    v = self.send(byte_view[count:])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1205, in send
    return self._sslobj.write(data)
ssl.SSLEOFError: EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:2396)
```

However, I have bypassed this error by converting the DF to a CSV, then reading it back as a DF:

```
i = 0
if (df_to_sheet(sheet, sheetName, df)):
     print("Sheet Posted:   ", sheetName)
else:
     print("No Sheet Posted:", sheetName)
     df.to_csv(csv_path + str(i), index=False)
     df = pd.read_csv(csv_path + str(i))
     if (df_to_sheet(sheet, sheetName, df)):
          print("Sheet Posted using workaround: ", sheetName)
     else:
          print("Still no Sheet Posted", sheetName)
     i += 1
```

In this case, the problematic sheets get posted using the workaround. I can see no reason that this workaround works, and, preferably, I would like to post everything without it. Does anyone understand the reason why I have to convert to a CSV first?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35419523/

Comment: I don't think the csv conversion does anything. I think because you retried at a different time, it went through.