# Paho MQTT C Client connection with azure IoT-Hub on Beaglebone Black

Tags: c, azure, cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, azure-iot-hub

I am trying to connect with Azure IoT-Hub with MQTT and send and receive messages using Paho C Client from Beaglebone black (OS: Debian Wheezy). I'm using eclipse CDT on Ubuntu machine to develop my application and deploy/debug remotely.

When i run the application on my native ubuntu machine (Compiled with gcc), Azure connection is success and i'm able to send packets.

I crosscompiled the OPENSSL as specified [here](https://how-to-build-for-arm.wikispaces.com/openssl) and copied the appropriate directories in "/usr/arm-linux-gnueabihf" folder. But when I compile with arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc-4.7 and remote debug on my beaglebone black (With gdb-multiarch) i'm getting the following error in my output console:

```
3068126320:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed:s3_clnt.c:1185:
3068126320:error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed:s3_clnt.c:1185:
Failed to connect, return code -1
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.Thanks.

**Edit: Suspected link - Reg:** The error in the suspected duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084886/ssl-error-routinesssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed) is same, but the OPENSSL error there is due to expired certificate. But in my case its during MQTT connection with azure & BBB. And moreover there is no answer for my question in that link. As per that link there is no point in disabling the certificate verification when we opt for SSL/TLS secured connection.

My code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "stdlib.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "MQTTClient.h"
#define PAYLOAD     "Hello World!"
#define QOS         1
#define TIMEOUT     10000L
#define TOPIC1       "devices/Manoj_Test/messages/events/"
#define ADDRESS     "ssl://xxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net:8883"
#define CLIENTID1    "Manoj_Test"

int main(void)
{
MQTTClient client;
MQTTClient_connectOptions conn_opts = MQTTClient_connectOptions_initializer;
MQTTClient_message pubmsg = MQTTClient_message_initializer;
MQTTClient_deliveryToken token;
int rc1;

MQTTClient_create(&client, ADDRESS, CLIENTID1, 1, NULL);
conn_opts.cleansession = 1;
conn_opts.username = "xxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net/Manoj_Test";
conn_opts.password = "SharedAccessSignature sr=xxxxxxxx.azure-devices.net%2fdevices%2fManoj_Test&sig=GyizT%2b7uyIpOkMJjTfN%2fpOZh9CnuQedNB%2bre2NrL1Kg%3d&se=1496395529";


 MQTTClient_setCallbacks(client, NULL, connlost, msgarrvd, delivered);


if ((rc1 = MQTTClient_connect(client, &conn_opts)) != MQTTCLIENT_SUCCESS)
{
    printf("Failed to connect, return code %d\n", rc1);
    exit(-1);
}

MQTTClient_subscribe(client, TOPIC, QOS);
while(1)
{
    pubmsg.payload = PAYLOAD;
    pubmsg.payloadlen = strlen(PAYLOAD);
    pubmsg.qos = 1;
    pubmsg.retained = 0;
    MQTTClient_publishMessage(client, TOPIC1, &pubmsg, &token);
    printf("Waiting for up to %d seconds for publication of %s\non topic %s for client with ClientID: %s\n", (int)(TIMEOUT/1000), PAYLOAD, TOPIC1, CLIENTID1);
    rc1 = MQTTClient_waitForCompletion(client, token, TIMEOUT);
    printf("Message with delivery token %d delivered\n", token);
    usleep(100000);
}
MQTTClient_disconnect(client, 10000);
MQTTClient_destroy(&client);
return rc1;
}
```

Comment: These errors are run-time, right? I've come across these errors too and for me it meant what it said: it couldn't verify the SSL certificate. I'm not sure if you can reach these services through a browser like Chrome, but if you can, you can check if Chrome gives you the same warning about the certificate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SSL error : routines:SSL3\_GET\_SERVER\_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084886/ssl-error-routinesssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed)

Comment: @bzeaman Yup. the errors are during runtime. I can't reach these services from browser as this is an MQTT broker over TCP. But i validated the same code built on ubuntu with gcc, and successfully connected to Azure.  And for my question suspected as duplicate see my post edit, and that link doesn't answer my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered using Azure IoT SDKs for connection to IoT Hub?  Debian is supported out-of-box and complexity with establishing the connection is abstracted.  You can read this [blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/benefits-of-using-the-azure-iot-sdks-in-your-azure-iot-solution/) for the benefits of using the SDKs.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue.
I obtained the server certificate from command line in .crt format and saved to /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ folder.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -connect server.edu:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null|openssl x509 -outform DER >mycertfile.crt
```

Then I updated the trust store certificates to add the above downloaded certificate,

```
update-ca-certificates
```

After updating i refered the ca-certificates file in my code,

```
conn_opts.ssl->trustStore = "/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt";
```