# Composer update fails with OpenSSL error

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm working on Windows 10 with WAMP 3.0.6 (Apache 2.4.23, PHP 5.6.25) and when I try to run `composer update`
It displays the error with OpenSSL:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
The "https://packagist.org/packages.json" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
https://packagist.org could not be fully loaded, package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
```

I have already set `openssl.cafile` variable in c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.25\php.ini and confirmed that this php.ini file is used by CLI.

Output of `php -r "var_dump(openssl_get_cert_locations());"`

```
array(8) {
  ["default_cert_file"]=>
  string(25) "c:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem"
  ["default_cert_file_env"]=>
  string(13) "SSL_CERT_FILE"
  ["default_cert_dir"]=>
  string(22) "c:/usr/local/ssl/certs"
  ["default_cert_dir_env"]=>
  string(12) "SSL_CERT_DIR"
  ["default_private_dir"]=>
  string(24) "c:/usr/local/ssl/private"
  ["default_default_cert_area"]=>
  string(16) "c:/usr/local/ssl"
  ["ini_cafile"]=>
  string(29) "c:/wamp/openssl/cacert.pem"
  ["ini_capath"]=>
  string(16) "c:/wamp/openssl/"
}
```

I downloaded certificate file from `http://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem` and tried to place it to different locations:

```
c:/wamp/openssl/
c:/usr/local/ssl/certs
c:/usr/local/ssl/cert.pem
```

I tried even reinstalling composer, using composer-setup.exe from getcomposer.org but it ends with the same error.

I searched stackoverflow and googled for hours but any of possible solutions have not worked. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Sounds more like an error with the certificate itself, rather than where it is? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17084886/ssl-error-routinesssl3-get-server-certificatecertificate-verify-failed

Comment: Possible duplicate of [file\_get\_contents(): SSL operation failed with code 1. And more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26148701/file-get-contents-ssl-operation-failed-with-code-1-and-more)

Answer (score 0):

Try to unset `https_proxy` enables composer to work!

Comment: sorry for dumb question, but where i have to unset https_proxy ?

Comment: This is what i get : 'unset' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Any luck solving the problem