# Python SSL module: how to turn on debug to display handshake in detail

Tags: python, ssl, handshake

In Perl, I can do

```
perl -MIO::Socket::SSL=debug4 my_program.pl
```

This displays SSL handshake in detail

```
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2649: new ctx 98842176
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:562: socket not yet connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:564: socket connected
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:586: ssl handshake not started
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:619: using SNI with hostname fundresearch.fidelity.com
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:654: request OCSP stapling
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:673: set socket to non-blocking to enforce timeout=180
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:686: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:689: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:699: ssl handshake in progress
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:709: waiting for fd to become ready: SSL wants a read first
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:729: socket ready, retrying connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:686: call Net::SSLeay::connect
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2552: did not get stapled OCSP response
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2505: ok=0 cert=102327360
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:689: done Net::SSLeay::connect -> -1
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:692: SSL connect attempt failed

DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:692: local error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:695: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: .../lib/Net/HTTPS.pm:69: ignoring less severe local error 'IO::Socket::IP configuration failed', keep 'SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed'
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2682: free ctx 98842176 open=98842176
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2687: free ctx 98842176 callback
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:2694: OK free ctx 98842176
Error GETing https://fundresearch.fidelity.com/mutual-funds/fees-and-prices/316343201: Can't connect to fundresearch.fidelity.com:443 at -e line 1.
```

see example in [Perl SSL debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48130596/wwwmechanize-ssl-connect-attempt-failed-for-https-get)

I'd like to use something similar to this in Python, from command line or inside python script, to display SSL handshake in detail.

Thank you