# Python: When using Requests package to perform a get request on a HTTPS page, how do I ensure that the sign in credentials are encripted

Tags: python, authentication, web-scraping, python-requests, ssl-certificate

So I'm using BeautifulSoup and Requests to get data from an https website

I know I need to provide authorisation details (I don't want to say verify=False)

Something like the solution in: [How do I scrape an https page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23416599/how-do-i-scrape-an-https-page)

How do I ensure that the login and password are protected and not sent as plain text (I'm a rookie)

Is there anything I need to consider here?

Comment: a get request doesnt have a payload/body, only headers and url parameters, so they can be scraped from the url

Comment: Based on your response I can see I need to read more ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the underlying technology concepts with regards to HTTP/S.

When you use BeautifulSoup, you Request a web page, and it returns the HTML. Some websites require you to authenticate to ensure content that is private remains protected.

A better question for you to ask would be:

"How do I use BeautifulSoup and Requests to scrape data from a website that requires authentication?"

And to that, I would answer, read the docs. Here is a link to get you started:
Requests Sessions - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v2.3.0/user/advanced/#session-objects