# Trusting self signed certificate with Python requests

Tags: python, apache, ssl, python-requests

My apache ssl conf has the following configs

```
#   Server Certificate:
SSLCertificateFile /etc/pki/tls/certs/localhost.crt

#   Server Private Key:
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/pki/tls/private/localhost.key
```

I do not have the CA certificates for this server. Can I still install the localhost.crt into my clients to successfully verify my server?

On the client:
I am using Python requests library (2.2.1). The default CA BUNDLE path is used. Even when I add the localhost.crt to the cacert.pem in the default path, I am unable to see the verification go through. I see the exception:

```
    File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 385, in send
    raise SSLError(e)
SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
```

Am I doing anything wrong? Should I only add the CA who signed the localhost.crt in the server?

Thanks,
Vijay

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but adding the SSLCertificateFile to the end of /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/cacert.pem does not work. Either I am copying to the wrong location or I am copying the wrong cert (signed cert instead of signing CA cert). I suspect the latter.

Comment: What is the URL to the server? Also, please provide the Python code, and not just the Python exception.

Answer (score 5):

If you provided code and be more clear on what you're doing then you'd get a good answer.

If you want don't want to get the error even if you use an invalid certificate then try the `verify=False` attribute.

`>>> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', verify=False)`

If you want to use a custom certificate, then place the certificate in the script folder and use the `cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key')` argument.

`>>> requests.get('https://kennethreitz.com', cert=('/path/client.cert', '/path/client.key'))`.

For more info read the [docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/) site