# Certificates repository in Python

Tags: python, ssl, certificate, python-requests

I'm using requests in python and I want to use SSL.

```
>>> requests.get('https://github.com', verify=True)
<Response [200]>
```

The documentation said:

> You can pass verify the path to a CA_BUNDLE file with certificates of trusted CAs. This list of trusted CAs can also be specified through the REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE environment variable.

Anyone know how to configure this environment variable or trust a certificate?

Thanks!!

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/a/58330834/1698736 shows how to use an entire local directory of public certificate files with requests.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into python-requests code:

```
            # Look for requests environment configuration and be compatible
            # with cURL.
            if verify is True or verify is None:
                verify = (os.environ.get('REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE') or
                          os.environ.get('CURL_CA_BUNDLE'))
```

so you'll have to set up either of those environment variables to make an SSL call.

set environment variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE:

```
$ export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/foo.crt
```

or set it to a directory

```
$ export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs
```

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

```
Note:
If verify is set to a path to a directory, the directory must have been
processed using the c_rehash utility supplied with OpenSSL.
```

so you have to rehash those certs in the directory:

```
$ cd /etc/ssl/certs
$ for i in *.crt; do ln -s $i $(openssl x509 -hash -noout -in $i).0; done
```

or

```
$ c_rehash /etc/ssl/certs
```

Comment: For anyone wondering how to get multiple .pem certificates into your CA_BUNDLE file, they can just be appended to each other in the same file.  Run `python -c "import requests; print(requests.certs.where())"`, and open the printed filepath to see an example.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `verify` to True should already use SSL:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification

Or, do you have a local certificate? (If that's what you wanted, you set `verify` to the absolute path to the cert.pem file.)

Comment: I have a local certificate from the server (I have exported the certificate from firefox) is a self-signed certificate. I have used the path to the cert.pem file but give me a exception. requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib <_ssl.c:2525>