# Exchangelib on Docker with custom SSL Certificates

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, dockerfile, ssl-certificate, exchangelib

I've built a Fastapi web app that relies on the library [exchangelib](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib). I'm working in an internal network, where a windows IIS signed a as root the certificate of the mail server. The certificate chain is made of only 2 levels: mail server certificate and root server certificate.

On an ubuntu 20.04 server I've added the two certificates under `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates` and updated the list via `sudo update-ca-certificates`. Until here it works with no problem.

When I use docker to build and run the container I get error message

```
exchangelib.errors.TransportError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='**********', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /EWS/Exchange.asmx (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1124)')))
```

Here's the Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.6-slim

WORKDIR .

COPY . .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

COPY ./ssl/CA.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/CA.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/CA.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

COPY ./ssl/server.crt /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt
RUN chmod 644 /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/server.crt
RUN update-ca-certificates

CMD [ "uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

I've changed the certificate permissions since I thought it would help, but with no result. Also, I run with every newly added certificate. But the certificates are added as `1 added` is printed on the terminal when the `RUN update-ca-certificates` command is run.

I'm not sure if it's an issue with docker or with the library. The same certificates work on the bare-metal server, but not on docker.

Can anyone help?
Thanks

I'm not understanding

Comment: You probably need to tell requests to use the copied certificates. See suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu

Comment: It seems to be root of the problem. Although even trying to set the environment variable in the dockerfile seems to be not working (the path to the python's certificates does not change).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after more than a week spent on checking my certificates and what was going on with docker, @Erik Cederstrand enlightened me, suggesting to check the `requests`'s certificate path.

It turned out that indeed it was set to a different location, not sure why. So, to be sure, I changed both `REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE` and `SSL_CERT_FILE` environment variables to point to my ca certificates file (which is the system one on ubuntu/debian).

Anyway, my final `Dockerfile` looks as follows

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

WORKDIR .

COPY . .

ENV SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
ENV REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

COPY ./ssl/* /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/

RUN update-ca-certificates

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "uvicorn", "app:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
```

Many thanks to @Erik Cederstrand