# SSL error in Python requests when in CentOS

Tags: python, python-requests, centos, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to use Python requests to access a URL from `https://dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br`, but it **fails in CentOS**. It works fine in Windows.

Here is the error:

```py
>>> import requests
>>> requests.__version__
'2.26.0'
>>> requests.get('https://dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br')Traceback (most recent call last):  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 696, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 964, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 426, in connect
    tls_in_tls=tls_in_tls,
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 450, in ssl_wrap_socket
    sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname=server_hostname
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 493, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 365, in wrap_socket
    _context=self, _session=session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 776, in __init__
    self.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 1036, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/ssl.py", line 648, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 756, in urlopen
    method, url, error=e, _pool=self, _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2]
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 574, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 542, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 655, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/python3/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:897)'),))
```

My CentOS version: `CentOS Linux release 8.4.2105`. It works in Windows 10. I'm using requests lib version 2.26.0.

I tried to download the certificate from the site and validate with it using this command:

```
requests.get('https://dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br', verify=True,
             cert='./bndes-gov-br.pem')
```

but got a *similar* exception. Here is the stack trace:

```
>>> requests.get('https://dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br', verify=True, cert='./bndes-gov-br.pem')  
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xxxxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    self._prepare_proxy(conn)
  File "/home/xxxxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 805, in _prepare_proxy
    conn.connect()
  File "/home/xxxxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 344, in connect  
    ssl_context=context)
  File "/home/xxxxx/lib/python3.7/site-packages/urllib3/util/ssl_.py", line 338, in ssl_wrap_socket
    context.load_cert_chain(certfile, keyfile)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3854)
```

Note that this error happens also in Python 3.7.

I exported the certificate following [these instructions](https://medium.com/@menakajain/export-download-ssl-certificate-from-server-site-url-bcfc41ea46a2)

Initially I tried to configure my machine global certificates, but it looks like Python and Requests lib [uses its own](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu). Another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835619/urllib-and-ssl-certificate-verify-failed-error) gave me a lot of valuable info to configure my certificate.

Since I couldn't make requests lib use my certificate, I believe there is an error in the downloaded certificate or in the validation lib.

Here is its contents of my `bndes-gov-br.pem` file downloaded using the browser (I got the same error trying with the complete certificate chain):

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

How do I configure Python 3.6 in CentOS so it access files in https://dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br without turning off SSL?

Answer (score 1):

As specified in the document: https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/, the `cert` option is used to specify the **client cert** instead of **server cert**. **Client cert** is what you (as client) provides to the web server, so it believes who you are, thus it's not what you need. Instead, **server cert** is what `https://dadosabertos.bndes.gov.br` provides for you so you know that you are talking to the real website. It's provided by the server during the SSL handshake so you don't need to mannually speicify it. Question here is that requests fail to validate the **server cert**.

I try to reproduce your result in Docker centos environment but it works without any problems. `requests` use root certificates provided by the `certifi` package. It's possible that your `certifi` package is out-of-data. So I guess you may uninstall `certifi` and `requests` package and reinstall to get a latest copy of trusted root certificates.

My `requests` and dependencies versions:

```
certifi-2021.10.8
charset-normalizer-2.0.7
idna-3.3
requests-2.26.0
urllib3-1.26.7
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm using the same libs your are using, and it still fails. Are you using the same CentOS version (8.4.2105)? Are you using python 3.6.8?

Comment: @neves I start the centos container by `docker run -it centos:8.4.2105 bash`, then install python3 using `dnf` and requests using `pip`. `dnf` installs python `3.6.8-38.module_el8.5.0+895+a459eca8`.