# How to solve API connection error and SSL certification error while connecting to GPT-3 open AI?

Tags: python-3.x, api, ssl-certificate, openai-api, gpt-3

I am trying to run a python script(jupyter notebook) by experimenting with GPT-3 open AI to create some NLP project and understand its functions and used cases. I got an error of SSL certification and API connection while I was trying to open a JSON file. I checked some solutions on the internet but it did not offer any remedy. I simply tried connecting to the server through API key but the code was not working. The code I executed is as follows-

```
import ssl
import certifi
certifi.where()
import openai
api_key='my_api_key'            #it is confidential string
openai.api_key = api_key
response = openai.File.create(file=open("C:\\Users\\pythons_scripts\\Corporate Governance1658287996.json"), purpose="search")
print(response)
```

So the above script is throwing all of the following errors-

```
SSLCertVerificationError                  Traceback (most recent call last)    
SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1129)
APIConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
APIConnectionError: Error communicating with OpenAI
```

Does anyone know how to get around with this ? or has anyone solved this kind of problem? can someone suggest a solution which will work?

Answer (score 3):

The OpenAI library is using the standard python requests under the hood. This means that you can set the CA Bundle using the following environment variable (found in [Python Requests - How to use system ca-certificates (debian/ubuntu)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu)).

Name: REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE

Value: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

Just remember to change the value to the actual path of your ca bundle file.

This has been tested and confirmed to work on Windows but should work across other platforms

Comment: Confirmed this works on WSL2 Ubuntu. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

same problem here, trying to use the API from a corporate network.
Unfortunately, in similar situations I have had to resort to disabling the SSL verification. I tried adding variations of verify_ssl=False and didn't work, also trying updating conda, certifi etc just in case.

Then I checked various api docs and even the codebase here: https://github.com/openai/openai-python/blob/main/openai/api_requestor.py  to see if there was any hint and saw there :

```
def _make_session() -> requests.Session:
    if not openai.verify_ssl_certs:
        warnings.warn("verify_ssl_certs is ignored; openai always verifies.")
```

It would look like the developers do not support disabling ssl as a principle.  Of course, this is little more than a guess, and I would be delighted to be proven wrong :)

Apologies for not solving your issue
Cheers!

Afterthought: you might consider trying another library/method. In https://beta.openai.com/docs/api-reference/introduction they say "You can interact with the API through HTTP requests from any language, via our official Python bindings, our official Node.js library, or a community-maintained library."