# Client certificate works in curl but not in Python

Tags: python, ssl, curl, python-requests

Using curl I can connect to a server that needs specific certificate.

```
curl -E ./file.crt.pem --key ./file.key.pem -k https://server.url
```

curl version: 7.29.0

But when using Python's requests library, I get an error:

```
import requests
cert_file_path = "file.crt.pem"
key_file_path = "file.key.pem"
cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)
url = 'https://server.url'
r = requests.post(url, cert=cert, verify=False)
```

Error:

```
SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'ssl3_read_bytes', 'tlsv1 alert unknown ca')])"))
```

Python version: v3.7

What am I missing?

Comment: Most likely because Python does not use the systems trusted cert store. Try this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42982143/python-requests-how-to-use-system-ca-certificates-debian-ubuntu

Comment: @RobertKearns I tried the solutions there, but none worked. I tried in golang as well, it gives handshake failure. I ended up writing a library for curl bindings...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A comment on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30405947/7487335) helped me figure this out.

Update your code as such:

```py
import requests
cert_file_path = "file.crt.pem"
key_file_path = "file.key.pem"
cert = (cert_file_path, key_file_path)
url = 'https://server.url'
r = requests.post(url, cert=cert, verify="path/to/ca_public_keys.pem") # replace with your file
```

I'm assuming you're using a self-signed certificate, so you need to specify the `.pem` file containing the public certificates of the CA that issued your self-signed certificate. **Make sure to include the intermediate certificates**, otherwise the requests library will throw the `tlsv1 alert unknown ca` error.

You can check the issuer of your client certificate by typing `openssl x509 -noout -in file.crt.pem -issuer` in a terminal.

Answer (score 2):

Request module checks environmental variable REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE for cert file.  So just do this

```
export REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE=/absolute/path/to/your/file.crt.pem
```

Your python code will simply be:

```
import requests

url = 'https://server.url'
r = requests.post(url)
print(r.text)
```