# Verify SSL certificate with Requests

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

I'm trying to verify SSL but it doesn't work.

1. I went on the confidential website I wanna get, on my browser.
2. On Chrome I've clicked on the locker > certificates > Details > copy in a file > base 64 > certif.cer

My code is :

```
test = requests.get('https://confidential.xx/', verify='certif.cer')
```

And the error is :

> File
> "C:\Users\xxxxx\Downloads\WinPython\WPy64-3850\python-3.8.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py",
> line 514, in send
> raise SSLError(e, request=request)
>
> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxxxx',
> port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by
> SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]
> certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate
> chain (_ssl.c:1123)')))

I don't wanna use verify=False which works but not securised.

I have tried with and without the proxies, same error...

I need to make this working, how make this code working please ?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405867/how-to-get-python-requests-to-trust-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate  Note: You must include the server's certificate and any intermediate certificates.

Comment: @AndrejKesely thanks, do you have any idea where I can find the intermediate certificates ?

Comment: I posted an answer with screenshots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To make `requests` not complain about valid certificate, the certificate supplied to `verify=` must contain any intermediate certificates. To download full chain, you can use Firefox (screenshots):

## Click on page info:

[image]

---

## Then download full PEM chain:

[image]

Comment: @Totopoildo What do you mean not available?

Comment: I cannot see the images. However, I have found two things in Firefow, which one can I choose please ? Download : PEM (cert) / PEM (chain)

Comment: @Totopoildo `PEM (chain)` contains the full chain. (Note: Strange, I can see the images. Are you behind proxy?)

Comment: yes I am but I did mistake i and L on my phone when I searched for the image. It seems to work thanks a lot !