# SSL verification fails with requests but not with urllib3

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I'm importing the certificates from anaconda.

```
import certifi
cert_path=certifi.where()
print("cert path", cert_path)
```

and I try to call an API with requests

```
import requests 
r = requests.post(url = API_ENDPOINT, data = data, headers=headers, verify = cert_path)
```

And it fails with

```
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: ... (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSLroutines', 'ssl3_get_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I've already resolved this issue **without requests** but following [urllib3 docs](http://%20https://urllib3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user-guide.html#ssl).

```
http = urllib3.PoolManager(
     cert_reqs='CERT_REQUIRED',
     ca_certs=certifi.where()
     )
r = http.request("POST", url = API_ENDPOINT, body = encoded_data, headers=headers)
```

Why aren't requests using urllib3 under the covers, and why is it failing, or what should I change in my code when using the requests module?
I've noticed the fascinating and helpful picture in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64225525/11323942), but - before downloading new certs - I'd like to understand the reason better because I would prefer to stay with my current urllib3 solution if the requests module can't work with my standard anaconda certs as well as urllib3 is doing.
Notice that "*downloading the appropriate intermediate certificate(s)*" is [already needed](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1135#issuecomment-286733578) for urllib3 AFAIK, so if urllib3 validation passes, that should not be a problem for requests either.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the issue, in my original anaconda cacerts bundle there is a certificate that is causing the issue, due to an **expiry date**, I think.