# api.loganalytics.io unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python-requests, ssl-certificate, azure-log-analytics

I've been using the code based on the snipped below for several months and it worked.

```
import requests

resp = requests.get(
        'https://api.loganalytics.io',
        # verify=False
)
```

Now I have an error:

File "C:....virtualenvs\pythonProject-XaZ9hdp4\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 563, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.loganalytics.io', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

I checked SSL certificate for api.loganalytics.io with third-party online service and it looks like everything is OK with its SSL certificate.

I created new Python project and re-install requests and certifi in new virtual environment.

What kind of another certificate can be meant in this error message? How can I find and update it?
I work under Windows 10.

Comment: The issue was resolved with solution from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64224608/verify-ssl-certificate-with-requests?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests 

resp = requests.get( 

        'https://api.loganalytics.io', 

        # verify=False 

)
```

In this code we need change Verify = false to verify=ssl.CERT_NONE

```
import requests 
   
resp = requests.get( 

        'https://api.loganalytics.io', 

         verify=ssl.CERT_NONE 

)
```

if you have any ssl certificate you can use this

```
s = requests.Session() 

s.cert = '/path/client.cert'
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's commented  # verify=False just to show I know about this possibility. Of course, in that case it works. But I need to understand what kind of SSL certificate I need and where should I place it to fix the issue? I do not want to modify my Python code. I need correct place to put correct SSL certificate or env variable.

Comment: Depends on the priority we can chose different types of ssl certificates please refer below doc:
https://serverguy.com/ssl/types-of-ssl-certificates/