# Python requests basic command returns errors - what's wrong?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I want to run these 3 commands:

```
import requests
result = requests.get("https://somedomain.xyz/start_page.html")
print(result.status_code)
```

but I get an error output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 386, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somedomain.xyz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bzo/en/start_page.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\TTNr.py", line 8, in 
    result = requests.get("https://somedomain.xyz/start_page.html")
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somedomain.xyz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /start_page.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

Does anyone know what could be a problem and how to solve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: //somedomain.xyz does not exist you might want to put an existing url in your get request method.

Comment: It's pretty clear from the error text. `Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain` - you're probably using a self-signed certificate for testing. Which by default is not trusted. You can pass `verify=False` to requests to bypass it if you trust the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import requests
result = requests.get("https://somedomain.xyz/start_page.html", verify=False)
print(result.status_code)
```

If you don't want to keep `verify=False`, then the path of the relevant certs need to be mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be accessing a site that uses a self-signed certificate. That will not be considered valid by default.

Have a look at: [How to get Python requests to trust a self signed SSL certificate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405867/how-to-get-python-requests-to-trust-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 670, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 381, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 978, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 362, in connect
    self.sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 386, in ssl_wrap_socket
    return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 500, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1040, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1309, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 439, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 726, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py", line 446, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somedomain.xyz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /bzo/en/start_page.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\TTNr.py", line 8, in 
    result = requests.get("https://somedomain.xyz/start_page.html")
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 76, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 530, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 643, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\usik\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 514, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='somedomain.xyz', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /start_page.html (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1108)')))
```

So this is what i did to fix it

```
import requests
import urllib3
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

urllib3.disable_warnings()
logging.captureWarnings(True)

url = ("url_here")

r = requests.get(url,verify=False)
# print(r.status_code)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text,"lxml")
print(soup)
```