# Python Request: SSL Verify

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, pyopenssl

I am using python request module to hit rest api. I have to use SSL for security measures.
I see that i can set

`requests.get(url,verify=/path/ca/bundle/)`

However i am confused as to what needs to be passed as CA_BUNDLE?

I get the server certificate using

`cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((server,port))`

Can someone let me know, how i should use this certificate in my request? Should i convert the cert to X509/.pem/.der/.crt file ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30405867/how-to-get-python-requests-to-trust-a-self-signed-ssl-certificate

Comment: Not enough information. Is it a self-signed certificate? Is it a leaf certificate signed by a custom CA?

Comment: I am getting the certificate using cert = ssl.get_server_certificate((server,port)). I am assuming its certificate signed by a custom CA

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Apparently i needed to get the entire certificate chain and create a CA bundle out of it.