# SSL Certi1ficate Issue: certificate verify failed: self-signed certificate in certificate chain

Tags: elasticsearch, ssl-certificate, elastic-stack, wsl-2, python-3.10

Hihi, i have been having issue trying to connect my SharePoint connector 2016 to elastic. My Elastic and Kibana are both running locally on Windows, while i trying to run my connector in WSL-Ubuntu. I have no issue running `curl -v https://localhost:9200` and it gives me the results here:

[image]

but when i try to run the connectiong using the command `make run`, it gives me error:

[image]
Not sure what the real problem here. I have tried to copy cert from my local machine to ubuntu following this thread: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED certificate verify failed : self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:992)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76578915/ssl-certificate-verify-failed-certificate-verify-failed-self-signed-certifica)

I also have tried `use_ssl: False` and `verify_certs: False`
Here are the versions i use:

Connector source : https://github.com/elastic/connectors

ElasticSearch: 8.12.2

Kibana: 8.12.2

WSL: 2.1.5.0

WSL Distro: Ubuntu

elasticsearch.yml

```
# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
```

connector config.yml

```
connectors:
-
  connector_id: "adrl8o0BJBmtFMDNEQQR"
  service_type: "sharepoint_server"
  api_key: "OVNnUFVJNEJHS3dvQy1XdVFEWFQ6NFZsWU5tc21ScHl4OXVLYzVzM0Z5dw=="
elasticsearch:
  host: "https://localhost:9200"
  api_key: "OVNnUFVJNEJHS3dvQy1XdVFEWFQ6NFZsWU5tc21ScHl4OXVLYzVzM0Z5dw=="
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that for the first command exactly `curl -v https://localhost:9200` was used, not e.g. `curl -v --insecure -u "elastic:changeme" https://localhost:9200`?

I don't know the client technology used here, but whenever there's secure connection with a self-signed certificate used, the certificate has to be either trusted or ignored by the client application.

In case of `curl` this is exactly what `--insecure` or `-k` is doing: using HTTPS regardless of the issuer of the certificate.

For the record: the client can't say "don't use secure connection" if the server requires one, hence telling the client `use_ssl: false` won't make things work. Unless SSL is disabled at server too (not recommended).

For production usage it may make sense to switch to trusted certificate. Or if self-signed is to be used, to make this CA trusted, e.g. by exporting it and then using with [elasticsearch.ca_certs](https://github.com/elastic/connectors/blob/37b1c5052cb5b229ffd8da0a317c347582b004c4/config.yml#L58)

Comment: hi yes, im sure its the first command. i get an empty reply from server using http instead of https. how do i know its self signed ? my elastic only got http_ca.crt, which is auto issued. so im not sure what to do from here since i got nthg on security knowledge.

Comment: Are you really sure the first command has only `-v` switch?
How come cURL is showing "your user name is elastic"?
It says so in the first screenshot, as long as this is self-signed.
This http_ca.crt is something you'd need to export and use in the connecter I'd say ;-)