Python ssl library not using a certificate that should be available on the machine
I'm facing a SSL issue when trying to use OpenAI python SDK library on Azure App Service. The issue seems to be comming from the fact that I'm connecting via API Gateway that uses company's self-signed certificate. When I try to connect I get the following error:
File "/opt/python/3.11.8/lib/python3.11/ssl.py", line 979, in do_handshake
self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1006)

So far I tried to add the certificate to the custm bundle by the following code:
def trust_certificate(cert_path, def_rel_path="app/tmp"):
    #this did not work since custom_ca_bundle is in read_only filesystem. Let's create a file in local
    custom_ca_bundle = certifi.where()
    try:
        with open(custom_ca_bundle, 'ab') as f:
            with open(cert_path, 'rb') as cert:
                f.write(cert.read())
        os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = custom_ca_bundle
        return custom_ca_bundle
    except OSError:
        #if cannot open existing certs for write, create aonother cert file
        local_ca_bundle = os.path.abspath(def_rel_path+"/local_cert.pem")
        # Get the directory path from the filename
        directory = os.path.dirname(local_ca_bundle)
        # Create the directory structure if it doesn't exist
        os.makedirs(directory, exist_ok=True)
        with open(local_ca_bundle, 'wb') as local_cert:
            #this will be our new bundle
            with open(custom_ca_bundle, 'rb') as python_cert:
                #these probably could not have been opened before
                with open(cert_path, 'rb') as cert:
                    #and this is our cert
                    #now all of them go to the new file
                    local_cert.write(python_cert.read())
                    local_cert.write(cert.read())
                    #from https://stackoverflow.com/a/69360645
                    os.environ["REQUESTS_CA_BUNDLE"] = local_ca_bundle
                    os.environ["SSL_CERT_FILE"] = local_ca_bundle
                    os.environ['SSL_CERT_DIR'] = directory
                    return local_ca_bundle

Without any success. I also added the certificate to Azure App service using Azure portal portal and verified that it works by using:
openssl s_client -connect <hostname>:443

which yields 0 (OK). However, the application is still not able to connect. To debug the issue I added a code to check the locations of certificate files used by various libraries from the code level, especially ones used by ssl.get_default_verify_paths(), certify.where() and openssl version -d. The results are the following (I'll not post the full code to print it here as it's a bit lengthy, can add it later though):
vp["pyssl_capath"] = openssl_obj.capath
vp["pyssl_openssl_capath"] = openssl_obj.openssl_capath
vp["pyssl_openssl_capath_env"] = openssl_obj.openssl_capath_env
vp["certifi"] = certifi.where()
arg0 = ["openssl", "version", "-d"]
ssl_cat_obj = subprocess.run(arg0,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
openssl_path = ssl_cat_obj.stdout.decode('utf-8').split("\"")[1]+"/certs"
vp["openssl"] = openssl_path
print(vp)
> {'pyssl_capath': '/tmp/8dca2683adac9c1/app/tmp', 'pyssl_openssl_capath': '/usr/lib/ssl/certs', 'pyssl_openssl_capath_env': 'SSL_CERT_DIR', 'certifi': '/agents/python/certifi/cacert.pem', 'openssl': '/usr/lib/ssl/certs'}

So, the certificate locations used by openssl s_client seem to  matching the ones present in output of python's ssl.get_default_verify_paths(), which confuses me a lot.
Finally, I tried calling openssl s_clent -connect using Python's subprocess lib for calling system functions:
#2. try to connect with default certificates
arg1 = ["openssl", "s_client", "-connect", f"{host}:443"]
ssl_try_def = subprocess.run(arg1,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
#2. Adding path cto folder containing my self-signed cert by hand
arg2 = ["openssl", "s_client", "-CApath", path, "-connect", f"{host}:443"]
ssl_try_path = subprocess.run(arg2,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

both ssl_try_def and ssl_try_path after this operation contain the same value returned in stderr section:
stderr: b'139809254405440:error:0200206F:system library:connect:Connection refused:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:\n139809254405440:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:\n139809254405440:error:02002063:system library:connect:Cannot assign requested address:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:110:\n139809254405440:error:2008A067:BIO routines:BIO_connect:connect error:../crypto/bio/b_sock2.c:111:\nconnect:errno=99\n'

All this confuses me a lot. I'm not an expert in SSL topics (more of a data science guy tbh), so any help or reference to docs will be appreciated! (for example I was never able to find out this SSL error no. 99)
Edit:
Since the call is made inside an SDK I cannot use this solution
Also, the Azure web app is running a linux machine, the call is made form a FastAPI based aplication, during startup

machine of Linux /Windows

Thanks for asking, it's a linux machine running FastApi app.

Using   company's self-signed certificate to connect with Azure App Service  via API Gateway  right? are using OpenAI python SDK library on Azure App Service with access  key and end point right.

connecting the application/Azure App Service on local right? is local machine of Linux /Windows.

The flow is the following: my backend (app service) uses Openai SDK to connect to APP gateway which connects to API manager which connects to Azure OpenAi. We are using managed identity if Im not wrong

could share full code. If code is big please share it git link.

Unfortunately I am not allowed due to company policy. :(
