# What is a ValueConstraintError with Python requests?

Tags: python, request, python-requests

I'm using the Python requests library to do a web-request:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(the_link)
```

but I'm getting a humongous `ValueConstraintError` which I'll paste below this message. I'm having a really hard time debugging this. The first weird thing is that I can't reproduce it in a test setup. I paste in the same url but I'm not getting the error then. I searched around for information about the `ValueConstraintError`, but I can't seem to find anything about it.

Could anybody give me some pointers as to what this error is about and how I can possibly debug this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./app/core.py", line 849, in scrapeEmail
    r = requests.get(link)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 55, in get
    return request('get', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/api.py", line 44, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 455, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 578, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 178, in resolve_redirects
    allow_redirects=False,
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 558, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 330, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 562, in urlopen
    body=body, headers=headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 979, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1013, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 975, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 835, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 797, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 145, in connect
    match_hostname(self.sock.getpeercert(),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 313, in getpeercert
    for value in get_subj_alt_name(x509)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/contrib/pyopenssl.py", line 94, in get_subj_alt_name
    asn1Spec=general_names)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 825, in __call__
    stGetValueDecoder, self, substrateFun
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/codec/ber/decoder.py", line 391, in valueDecoder
    r.verifySizeSpec()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/base.py", line 252, in verifySizeSpec
    def verifySizeSpec(self): self._sizeSpec(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pyasn1/type/constraint.py", line 32, in __call__
    '%s failed at: \"%s\"' % (self, sys.exc_info()[1])
ValueConstraintError: ConstraintsIntersection(ConstraintsIntersection(), ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64)) failed at: "ValueSizeConstraint(1, 64) failed at: "SubjectAltName().setComponents(GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('api.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('ax.init.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('bookkeeper.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('c.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('client-api.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('du.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('dzc.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('feeds.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('files.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('genius-2.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('genius-download-2.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('genius-download.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('genius-upload-2.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('genius-upload.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('genius.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('init.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('itunesu.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('ld-1.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('ld-2.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')), NamedType('value', Any(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0))))), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=32, tagId=0)))), NamedType('rfc822Name', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=1)))), NamedType('dNSName', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), NamedType('directoryName', Name(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('', RDNSequence())), tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=4)))), NamedType('uniformResourceIdentifier', IA5String(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=6)))), NamedType('iPAddress', OctetString(tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=7)))), NamedType('registeredID', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')))).setComponents(None, None, IA5String('ld-3.itunes.apple.com', tagSet=TagSet((), Tag(tagClass=128, tagFormat=0, tagId=2)))), GeneralName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('otherName', AnotherName(componentType=NamedTypes(NamedType('type-id', ObjectIdentifier('<no value>')),  etc. etc. etc. etc.
```

Comment: what is the value of `the_link`?

Comment: Something's wrong with the SSL certificate; Python was unable to decode the certificate information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same error this morning, and building on Martijn's hint above went looking for answers on how to deal with problem SSL certificates in requests.

This gave a clue: [Python Requests throwing up SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror)

Try this:

```
import requests
r = requests.get(the_link, verify=False)
```

details on the verify parameter can be found here:

http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/