# I am trying to access some twitter user id's using api.lookup_user , but when i run this , i get tweeperror

Tags: python, api, twitterapi-python

i am trying to get access to some user info from Twitter API using api.lookup_users . getting this error when i ran below code .

```
import tweepy 

consumer_key = "" 
consumer_secret = "" 
access_token = "" 
access_token_secret = "" 
   
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret) 
   
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret) 
  
api = tweepy.API(auth) 
user_ids = [57741058, 4802800777, 1037141442] 
  
users = api.lookup_users(user_ids)
```

TweepError: Failed to send request: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.twitter.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /1.1/users/lookup.json?user_id=572332655397629952%2C551659627872415744 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1123)')))

Answer (score 0):

as u can see in the error this is a SSL failiur.
check this [link](https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/basics/authentication/guides/tls) for more info.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37349419/tweepy-sslerror-regarding-ssl-certificate) also might help