# python SSL error when using request

Tags: python, ssl, https, get, request

I need to write a simple test script for rest get using python. What I have is:

```
import request
url = 'http://myurl......net'
headers ={'content-type':'application/xml'}
r= requests.get(url,headers=headers)
```

so this give me the following SSL error:
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed(_ssl.c:590)

So, i did some research and add " verify = False" to the end of my last line of code, but not I am stuck with: : InsecureRequestsWarning, Unverified request is been made. Addig certificate verification is strongly advised."

What to do to get rid of this message?

Comment: Why would you get an SSL error on an `http:` request?  Is the site automatically redirecting you to `https:`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Requests throwing up SSLError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror)

Comment: What OS are you running?

Comment: I am using mac El Capitan