# noVNC websockify ssl

Tags: ssl, websockify, novnc

I am trying to access noVNC through https on my local home sandbox using Websockify on Ubuntu 16 --> https://ubuntu:6080/vnc.html?host=ubuntu&port=6080

Steps so far taken:

1.Self signed a certificate for testing on my localhost which I can access even though it has a red line through the https b/c of the cert.

2.Downloaded latest noVNC and websockify.

3.Place websockify in utils dir of noVNC.

If I run noVNC via launch.sh:

```
utils/launch.sh --vnc localhost:5901 --cert ./lib/
```

Where lib has the self signed .key, .pem, and .csr my bash reads:

```
Starting webserver and WebSockets proxy on port 6080
WARNING: no 'numpy' module, HyBi protocol will be slower
WebSocket server settings:
  - Listen on :6080
  - Flash security policy server
  - Web server. Web root: /home/testuser/app/novnc
  - SSL/TLS support
  - proxying from :6080 to localhost:5901


Navigate to this URL:

    http://ubuntu:6080/vnc.html?host=ubuntu&port=6080

Press Ctrl-C to exit
```

When I go to my browser and load the url shown above I get the vnc.html page. However, when I put https instead of http (my original requirement) I get the following error:

```
*handler exception: [Errno 336265225] _ssl.c:355: error:140B0009:SSL routines:SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file:PEM lib*
```

Upon further review I have found a [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-up-sslerror) who directs this same error to a python issue that may be remedied with verify=False. However before I go down a rabbit hole I know nothing about I thought I'd ask if anybody knows why I cannot access noVNC through https?

Answer (score 4):

Your command contains parameter `--cert ./lib/`, where /lib/ is a directory.

According to `man websockify` you should use the following options:

```
    --cert=CERT        SSL certificate file                
    --key=KEY          SSL key file (if separate from cert)
```