# Python requests SSL error - certificate verify failed

Tags: python, ssl, https, python-requests, ssl-certificate

This code

```
import requests
requests.get("https://hcaidcs.phe.org.uk/WebPages/GeneralHomePage.aspx")
```

is giving me this error

```
[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:777)
```

I know practically nothing about SSL, but I've tried downloading the site's certificate and pointing to that file using the `verify` option, but it hasn't worked. Am I missing something?

Comment: Which version of Python and operating system are you using?

Comment: Yes sorry, Python 3.6.3 and Windows 7

Comment: The site has a bad SSL Implementation: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=hcaidcs.phe.org.uk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

Comment: check your system proxy settings, maybe you have set a unavailable proxy.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

As already pointed out in a comment: the site has a bad SSL implementation as can be seen from the [SSLLabs report](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=hcaidcs.phe.org.uk). The main part of this report regarding your problem is:

> This server's certificate chain is incomplete. Grade capped to B.

This means that the server is not sending the full certificate chain as is needed to verify the certificate. This means you need to add the missing certificates yourself when validating. For this you need to include the PEM for the missing chain certificate [C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert SHA2 High Assurance Server CA](https://www.censys.io/certificates/19400be5b7a31fb733917700789d2f0a2471c0c9d506c0e504c06c16d7cb17c0/pem) and also for the root CA [C=US, O=DigiCert Inc, OU=www.digicert.com, CN=DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA](https://www.censys.io/certificates/7431e5f4c3c1ce4690774f0b61e05440883ba9a01ed00ba6abd7806ed3b118cf/pem) info a file `my_trust_store.pem` and then you can call:

```
requests.get("https://...", verify='my_trust_store.pem')
```

> ... but I've tried downloading the site's certificate and pointing to that file using the verify option

This will not work with normal leaf certificates. Since the SSL stack of Python is based on OpenSSL and OpenSSL expects only trusted certificate authorities in the trust store (i.e. given with `verify`) and a server certificate is not CA certificate it will not help to add it to the trust store.

Comment: From the SSLLabs report, you can download the complete certificate chain with intermediates and root. Click "Click here to expand" under "Certification Paths", and then click the faint download icon next to the path whose chain you'd like to download.  Save this as a .pem file, and its path can be used as the argument to `verify=`.

Comment: The last paragraph helped me solve the error finally. Thank you for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

```
cat institution-certificate.pem >> venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

This should solve the problem if your network requires a CA

Comment: Since I had my institution's certificate handy, this was the easiest and most robust solution.

Comment: I smell a handy integration with something like https://pypi.org/project/get-certificate-chain/

Answer (score 2):

using the certifi doesn't seem to be implied, so i'll show you what made my solution:

```
import urllib, urllib2, ssl
import certifi

request = urllib2.Request(url=url)
kw = dict()
if url.startswith('https://'):
    certifi_context = ssl.create_default_context(cafile=certifi.where())
    kw.update(context=certifi_context)
urllib2.urlopen(request, **kw)
```

[i found this solution and more on RealPython, here](https://realpython.com/urllib-request/#fixing-the-ssl-certificate_verify_failed-error)

Answer (score -2):

If you can avoid the certificate verification (not secure), set PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY environment variable to 0:

```
export PYTHONHTTPSVERIFY=0
```

This will skip the certificate verification.

Comment: Did not work for me. What library uses this variable? `requests` certainly does not.

Comment: @redbeam_ This turn certificate verification off which is turned on by default. You can refer https://access.redhat.com/articles/2039753

Answer (score -3):

```
import requests
html = requests.get("https://hcaidcs.phe.org.uk/WebPages/GeneralHomePage.aspx",verify=False).text
```

**You should write it like this, and I've verified it**

Comment: If you want to get additional information from the asker, please use the comments. Answers which are just a shot into the blue might get downvoted.

Comment: This simply disables any kind of certificate validation. This should only be used for testing but never in production since it opens the application to man in the middle attacks.

Comment: Good enough for home scripting IMO. Good answer

Comment: good answer for self experimentation but i would suggest adding a warning/disclaimer in your answer

Comment: "You should write it like this." You should not, except for some very rare circumstances. Please do not write encouraging statements like this when it comes to network security.