# I am trying to retrieve a URL but keep running into an SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='developer.uspto.gov', port=443)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib

I am trying to retrieve a URL from an API set up by the USPTO. Their system provides a URL for the query, and it works just fine when searched in a web browser. But I keep receiving this error when doing so in Python3

I have tried using both urllib and requests to retrieve the data.

**My code:**

```
import requests

link = new_url
f = requests.get("https://developer.uspto.gov/ibd-api/v1/patent/application?searchText=device&start=0&rows=2000")
print(f.text)
```

**Error:**

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='developer.uspto.gov', port=443): Max 
retries exceeded with url: /ibd-api/v1/patent/application? 
searchText=device&start=0&rows=2000 (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad 
handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 
'certificate verify failed')])")))
```

I would like to be able to read the content of this URL using the json library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can easily be solved using by adding `verify = False` to your get request.

I would recommend replacing your current code with this one:

```
import requests

link = new_url
f = requests.get("https://developer.uspto.gov/ibd-api/v1/patent/application?searchText=device&start=0&rows=2000", verify=False)
print(f.text)
```

[Here](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#ssl-cert-verification) is a bit more info SSL Cert Verification.

hope this helps

Comment: This is effectively the same as doing `verify=False`. It'll work, but it's not the ideal approach and can leave the request open to MITM attacks.

Comment: @b_c that's a fair point, I'll modify my answer right now (replacing `ssl.CERT_NONE` with just `False`). But as far as I understand OP just wants to get information from a source, he isn't trying to build an API.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your URL is suffering from the same problem that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46604114/python-requests-ssl-error-certificate-verify-failed) was seeing ([accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46604917/4739755) describes the problem; [Here's the SSLLabs report on the host](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=developer.uspto.gov&s=54.87.215.129))

I was able to fix the SSL problem by downloading the cert from your original URL, exporting the two Entrust certificates to their own files (Entrust Certification Authority - L1K & Entrust.net), and then creating a `.pem` trust chain out of them (the Entrust L1K cert is missing in the response):

```
cat entrustL1K.cer entrustNET.cer > entrust_chain.pem
```

Then, you can pass this trust chain to the `requests.get` to fix the response:

```
url = "https://developer.uspto.gov/ibd-api/v1/patent/application?searchText=device&start=0&rows=2000"
requests.get(url, verify='entrust_chain.pem')

>>> <Response [200]>
```