# Google API key not working on server but working fine on local server

Tags: python, django, google-api

I am really new to Google API key.
When am I testing my code on the local system, it is working fine but on an actual server it giving me `SSLHandshakeError`.

**Server configuration**: `nginx + unicorn + ubuntu + django + Python 2.7`

`SSLHandshakeError at 'url'
[Errno 1] _ssl.c:510: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed`

Comment: What is the "actual server" running?

Comment: I mean to say that live site

Comment: What indicates that this is a Google API issue and not a SSL certificate problem? Post some relevant code besides just the error message

Answer (score 0):

This is due to untrusted SSL certificate. I'm assuming you're using python requests library and if that's the case, you can follow the instructions from the below link:

[Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

This might have also been caused if you entered wrong URL in your Google console. For instance, you might've whitelisted only your development server's url and not your production url maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution for my question, the error was coming due to package httplib2.
I have just updated `requests` and `httplib2`.

`pip install -U httplib2`

`pip install -U requests[security]`