# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED Error in Django running through uwsgi on nginx webserver

Tags: python, django, python-requests, ssl-certificate, uwsgi

I am running Django REST API project through `uwsgi` in `nginx` webserver.
Also configured `ssl` for HTTPS.

In project directory there are certificate & key files (as below), which helps to establish the secured HTTPS connection.

1. /my-project/test-cert.pem
2. /my-project/test-cert.KEY

I have checked from browser, the `https://mysite.domain.com/` is returning all the APIs, and the `https://mysite.domain.com/admin/` is returning the Django Admin page.

This means the Django is responding properly.

I am facing error in calling my internal APIs through external web URLs.

`https://mysite.domain.com/api/account/` is my web url which will call the `https://mysite.domain.com/user-list-details/`api internally.

Both the above APIs (`/api/account/` & `/user-list-details/`) are mentioned in my Django `urls.py`.

The sequence is that API-1 will be called from my Angular front-end and API-2 will be called **internally** by Django REST. API-2 will fetch data from DB and returns back to Angular through API-1.

This structure is basically designed to serve the purpose of our business logic and was working fine for HTTP version of my project but now I am facing issue after implementing **HTTPS**.

Sample code of internal API call:

```
import requests

# I have tried with three different certificates available. 

CERT_1 = '/etc/ssl/certs/ca-bundle.crt'
CERT_2 = '/my-project/test-cert.pem'
CERT_3 = '/tech/lib/python3.5/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem'

url = 'https://mysite.domain.com/user-list-details/'
apisession = requests.Session()
response = apisession.get(url, verify=CERT_1) # <= Error in this line
```

Error:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='', port=443); Max reties exceeded with url: /user-list-details/?query=all&name=Jhon (caused by SSLError(SSLError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:645)'),))

I have tried using the bundle certificate (`CERT_1`), but for that I am getting 504 error. 
I tried `verify=False` though not recommended, but getting 504 error.

I have checked similar posts as this: 
[Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)
but didn't get any way out.

I also learned from http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/

> The private key to your local certificate must be unencrypted. Currently, Requests does not support using encrypted keys.

So, is there something I am missing in Django settings? or is it possible to use **self signed certificate** for this?

Comment: Let me know if someone has any solution for this problem.

Comment: Anyone have any solution for this issue.. please share thought.

Answer (score 0):

Check the interface where you are calling the internal APIs from external requests.
External requests are Https call and this one is http call. So https to/from http will face the problem. Convert them also in https call. It might help. Please post if it helps.

Comment: Both Internal & External calls are now HTTPS, configured using SSL certs and hosted via uwsgi in nginx server. See the above codes.