# SSL Error for return redirect(auth.login())

Tags: python, flask, saml

I am trying to do SAML integration for my flask app but when i do `return redirect(auth.login())` i get an SSL Error as follows:

```
SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='adfs.lab01.mytestadfsserver.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /adfs/ls/?SAMLRequest=nVNNj9owEL3vr4hyz%2BfyJQsdsdsdsffgertrrgro7QPvra3vZwkoth%2BZiZebNm%2Bc347GGpm7JtDMHscEfHWrzEATnphaa%2BNQk7JQgEjTXRECDmhhKttOPS5LHKWmVNJLKOnxVdL8GtEZluBSuaDGfhOvV2%2BX6%2FWL1lY4qHOU5pTnk%2BSCF4QBT%2Bpj3hwNKq16K%2FdGeYj7rfe3rfefefrtgrgDoFTyyBmqle04CbdlYOxlfA%2BtO1wIbUAYi0%2BzUZSlUfq4y3ok65N88MWh5hbNBRhPejCm1SRJgFU6rmGfZjGtZces9k4hi6lsfC6pdeKKy4sPb7hgXDzdN2D%2FDNLkw25XRuV6u3MU0xdbefefefefetllc935XaPzWHb71ejGekncEIWh53OkLQJspiaOCXFHDSXiLDY1h4c8ZuLsQ7oYr%2FZ0saNMDAwDi5Jby2aImzfzEvZc3pTx933zupGjD%2FtiWLMx%2FhLKo8lHRCt0h5xZGFf2imdS1PM4Vg7ISN6jAMklfNLyuMzC%2B0ddLg2QQz2bSguHaTxTNQczHlaswtfFbbKW%2BwKu4uMSXU4Wy4tMdJKuZ2AKntvVNgxUtlLib9lfxZdXJHdvHwkr59ncVv&RelayState=https%3A%2F%2Fkey333hj44.execute-api.test.myserviceprovider.com%2F (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')],)",),))
```

I found this link : [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror) related to the error i am getting but i would like something like this for `return redirect(auth.login())`

Is there any way we can ignore certificate error for `return redirect(auth.login())` like it is done for requests by specifying `verify=False`? `(requests.get('https://example.com', verify=False))`

Here is a sample of my code:

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    req = prepare_flask_request(request)
    auth = init_saml_auth(req)
    return redirect(auth.login())
```

Comment: Generally `Max retries` is when you have an endless recurrtion, correct me if I'm wrong `auth.login()` is a recurrtion with no break point.

Comment: That's correct but the root cause of the issue is that redirect is attempting to verify self-signed cert. Since request has a verify=False, i would think there has to be way to do the same with redirects.