# Failed get request using Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I am reading the book "The Ultimate Guide to Web Crawling"

The code used to run the first HTTP get-request is the following:

```
import requests 
url = "https://scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/" 
r = requests.get(url) 
print("We got a {} response code from {}".format(r.status_code, url))
```

I got the error message:

> HTTPSConnectionPool(host='scrapethissite.com', port=443): Max retries
> exceeded with url: /pages/simple/ (Caused by SSLError(SSLError(1,
> '[SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)')))

I understand that my request doesn't go the right port. Is it linked to the fact that the website uses the communication protocol HTTPS (vs HTTP)? I am not sure, but it seems to be part of the problem.

I am using Python 3.8 on PyCharm. My SSL version is:

> OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020

I am a beginner in webcrawling. This is why I chose to run an alternative code to run my HTTP get-request, one that would allow me to select the appropriate port and protocol (Source: https://pythonprogramming.net/python-sockets/):

```
import socket
import ssl    

context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

server = 'scrapethissite.com'
port = 443
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=server)

request = "GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: "+server+"\n\n"

s.connect((server, port))
s.send(request.encode())
result = s.recv(4096)

while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(4096)
```

I got the HTTP 200 OK status response so it is working well. I get this output in the PyCharm terminal:

> b'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nDate: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 14:59:35
> GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nTransfer-Encoding:
> chunked\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nSet-Cookie:
> __cfduid=d205b0b8e8ce061174412767189bf10b41610463575; expires=Thu, 11-Feb-21 14:59:35 GMT; path=/; domain=.scrapethissite.com; HttpOnly;
> SameSite=Lax\r\nCF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC\r\ncf-request-id:
> 0798b515a60000ea04f707d000000001\r\nExpect-CT: max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"\r\nReport-To:
> {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=%2FROG7Z2JWZJBMeVNn1IgnJh2TZsqJCi9TJOL3zau98btlLo1nPg4WhGlmOz2SZ6PRep6%2BKZfv0M81fqKOw1l6%2BRbc5M9dErdtyeTsei9Ee%2F2jc0%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}\r\nNEL:
> {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}\r\nServer:
> cloudflare\r\nCF-RAY: 6107be029e27ea04-IAD\r\n\r\n1fb5\r\n<!doctype
> html>\n\n  \n    \n
>
> Scrape This Site | A public sandbox for learning web
> scraping\n    \n\n    \n    \n\n    \n    \n    \n\n    \n\n 
> \n\n  \n    \n            \n                \n         
> \n                        \n                            \n                               
> \n           
> Scrape This Site\n                            \n                  
> \n                        \n                
> \n                               
> \n     
> Sandbox\n                            \n                       
> \n                        \n                
> \n                               
> \n   
> Lesson' b's\n                            \n                       
> \n                        \n                    
> \n                                \n           
> FAQ\n                            \n                        \n
> \n                        \n    
> \n                               
> Login\n                            \n                       
> \n                        \n                    \n          
> \n            \n        \n\n        \n            var path =
> document.location.pathname;\n            var tab = undefined;\n       
> if (path === "/"){\n                tab =
> document.querySelector("#nav-homepage");\n            } else if
> (path.indexOf("/faq/") === 0){\n                tab =
> document.querySelector("#nav-faq");\n            } else if
> (path.indexOf("/lessons/") === 0){\n                tab =
> document.querySelector("#nav-lessons");\n            } else if
> (path.indexOf("/pages/") === 0) {\n                tab =
> document.querySelector("#nav-sandbox");\n            } else if
> (path.indexOf("/login/") === 0) {\n                tab = do'
> b'cument.querySelector("#nav-login");\n            }\n           
> tab.classList.add("active")\n        \n\n    \n\n    \n\n        \n            \n                \n               
> \n                        \n
>
> ## \n                            Scrape This Site\n
>
> \n                        \n                     
> The internet\'s best resource for learning **web
> scraping**.\n                        \n                    
>
> \n                        Explore Sandbox\n                        \n                  
> \n                       
> Begin Lessons →\n                        \n                  
> \n                \n           
> \n        \n\n    \n\n\n   
> \n        \n           
> \n                \n                    Lessons and Videos © Hartley
> Bro' b'dy 2018\n                \n           
> \n        \n    \n 
> \n\n  \n
> \n\n  \n\n  \n
> \n\n  \n 
> \n    \n   
> PNotify.prototype.options.styling = "bootstrap3";\n    $(function(){\n
> \n    });\n    \n\n    $(function () {\n     
> $(\'[data-toggle="tooltip"]\').tooltip()\n    })\n  \n\n 
> \n  \n   
> $("video").hover(function() {\n        $(this).prop("controls",
> true);\n    }, function() {\n        $(this).prop("controls",
> false);\n    });\n\n    $("video").click(function() {\n        if(
> this.paused){\n            this.play();\n        }\n        else {\n  
> this.pause();\n        }\n    });\n    \n\n  \n  \n   
> (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i[\'GoogleAnalyticsObject\']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){\n
> (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new
> Date();a=s.createElement(o),\n   
> m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)\n
> })(window,document,\'script\',\'https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js\',\'ga\');\n\n
> ga(\'create\', \'UA-41551755-8\', \'auto\');\n    ga(\'send\',
> \'pageview\');\n  \n\n  \n 
> \n 
> !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?\n
> n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;\n
> n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version=\'2.0\';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;\n
> t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,\n
> document,\'script\',\'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js\');\n\n
> fbq(\'init\', \'764287443701341\');\n  fbq(\'track\',
> "PageView");\n  \n  \n\n  \n  \n   
> /*  */\n    \n   
> \n   
> \n    \n    \n    \n
> \n  \n\n  \n  \n
> \n   window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];\n   function
> gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}\n   gtag(\'js\', new Date());\n\n  
> gtag(\'config\', \'AW-950945448\');\n  \n\n\r\n'
> b'0\r\n\r\n'

The only problem is that I want to scrape this website:

https://scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/

and not:

https://scrapethissite.com

When I replace

```
server = 'scrapethissite.com'
```

by:

```
server = 'scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/'
```

in the previous code, I get this new error message:

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

My understanding is that the problem is linked to the proxy. Knowing that the problem may be linked to port, socket, proxy, etc., is informative, but I am not sure what/how to fix the code as it is working fine for one website but not the other.

Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you!

---

Following OneCricketeer's reply, the code is now:

```
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()

server = 'scrapethissite.com'
port = 443
server_ip = socket.gethostbyname(server)

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s = context.wrap_socket(s, server_hostname=server)

request = "GET /pages/simple HTTP/1.1\nHost: "+server+"\n\n"

s.connect((server, port))
s.send(request.encode())
result = s.recv(4096)

while (len(result) > 0):
    print(result)
    result = s.recv(4096)
```

I get HTTP 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY status response.

> b'HTTP/1.1 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY\r\nDate: Tue, 12 Jan 2021 15:34:15
> GMT\r\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\nTransfer-Encoding:
> chunked\r\nConnection: keep-alive\r\nSet-Cookie:
> __cfduid=d6e32136f617c0b90e7f92a3e391c159f1610465655; expires=Thu, 11-Feb-21 15:34:15 GMT; path=/; domain=.scrapethissite.com; HttpOnly;
> SameSite=Lax\r\nLocation:
> [https://scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/\r\nCF-Cache-Status](https://scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/%5Cr%5CnCF-Cache-Status):
> DYNAMIC\r\ncf-request-id:
> 0798d4d0d700002550fc1c3000000001\r\nExpect-CT: max-age=604800,
> report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"\r\nReport-To:
> {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=2moOTvTDPvS65D6d0LvsiZTLDqYcv8OFZvtunIQDq6H%2FKLucm1LOOlMABcnCUjUO9fK4bwd%2BVDiescQ0NyHbu3DxhTCkOUHTvMcilkM%2BdcZnz3A%3D"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}\r\nNEL:
> {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}\r\nServer:
> cloudflare\r\nCF-RAY: 6107f0c7bb432550-IAD\r\n\r\n11f\r\n\nRedirecting...\n
>
> ## Redirecting...
>
> \n
>
> You
> should be redirected automatically to target URL: https://scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/.
> If not click the link.\r\n' b'0\r\n\r\n'

Is there something I missed?

Comment: Can you try with this? requests.get(url, verify=True)

Comment: @DivakarPatil I get the error message: `httpx.ProxyError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:1123)`

Comment: Try fixes from answers given here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am using Python 3.8 on PyCharm

Based on your `print` usage, you are actually using Python2...

In any case, this solution might work for the requests way

```
import requests 
url = "https://scrapethissite.com/pages/simple/" 
r = requests.get(url, verify=False)
```

If you want to use the socket method, you would change `GET /` to `GET /pages/simple`, and keep the `server` as just the domain name

> I understand that my request doesn't go the right port.

443 is the correct HTTPS port. The error is stating the SSL version is incorrect

Comment: @OneCricketeerThank you for your reply! Now I get the HTTP 301 MOVED PERMANENTLY status response. What is wrong?

Comment: You'll need to follow redirects... Not sure how to do what with sockets, but you can read the full response, and it should have something like a Location header