# Python Get API request is failing with SLA certificate

Tags: python-3.x, ssl

I am new to Python and I'm trying to get the data from Nasa API by using this code.

```
import requests
data = requests.get('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json')
```

Then it fails with the following error

```
SSLError:  HTTPSConnectionPool(host='data.nasa.gov', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /resource/gh4g-9sfh.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1122)')))
```

I think it was looking for some SSL Certificate which I have no idea how to get. Since anyway it was for practising and nothing important I used the verification to False but that gives some other error.

```
data = requests.get('https://data.nasa.gov/resource/gh4g-9sfh.json',verify='False')
```

Which gives me the following error:

```
OSError: Could not find a suitable TLS CA certificate bundle, invalid path: False
```

Although the error message has changed, looks like it's still expecting some sort of certificate.

What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Requests throwing SSLError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667960/python-requests-throwing-sslerror)

Comment: Note that in `verify='False'`, `'False'` is a _string_.